# Solve[ ] with Method -> Reduce gives a different result than Reduce[ ]

Tags: equation-solving

Why does

```
Solve[Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x]] - Sqrt[x - Sqrt[x]] ==
      m Sqrt[x/(x + Sqrt[x])], x, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
```

give a different result than

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x]] - Sqrt[x - Sqrt[x]] ==
       m Sqrt[x/(x + Sqrt[x])], x, Reals]
```

note that the first one says $1<m<2$ while the second one says $1<m\le 2$.
The documentation says

> With `Method->Reduce`, `Solve` uses only equivalent transformations and finds all solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solve by default works with generic parameters, even if you use the option `Method -> Reduce`. To get the special parameter value `m = 2` you need to set `MaxExtraConditions` to `All`:

```
Solve[Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x]] - Sqrt[x - Sqrt[x]] == m Sqrt[x/(x + Sqrt[x])], x, Reals, 
    Method -> Reduce, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Out[1]= {{x -> ConditionalExpression[(4 - 8 m + 8 m^2 - 4 m^3 + m^4)/(4 - 8 m + 4 m^2),
    1 < m <= 2]}}
```

Comment: As discussed in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) thread, Even both `Method -> Reduce, MaxExtraConditions -> All` are turned on, Solve and Reduce could give different results. For example, `Solve[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}, Method -> Reduce, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> All]`, and the Reduce counterpart.