# What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, function-comparison

`Solve` and `Reduce` both can be used for solving equations.

Just by working with them, I know there are some differences between them. but that is about all I know, and I want to know what the differences are.

Could someone teach me about this?

Comment: Another difference is mentioned in [Inequalities with assumptions and constraints](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23165/245): `Reduce` doesn't use `Assumptions`.

Answer (score 108):

In **Some Notes on Internal Implementation** especially in [Algebra and Calculus](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#7441) one finds interesting subtleties and differences between these two functions, e.g.

> ```
> The code for Solve and related functions is about 500 pages long.   
>
> Reduce and related functions use about 350 pages of Mathematica code 
> and 1400 pages of C code.
> ```

There is much more than a little difference between them. The most important is :

- **Reduce returns results of computation as boolean formulae and gives  complete description of solution sets.**
- **Solve returns lists of replacement rules yielding generic solutions.**

An important step toward more complete description of solution sets was a new option of `Solve` in `Mathematica 8`, namely  [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) (default value `0`). Using `MaxExtraConditions -> All` in `Solve` provides complete solutions for algebraic equations, nevertheless we have to emphasize that sometimes  **we might better work with Reduce rather than Solve (regardless of any options added) because replacement rules may appear not a good fit in description of solutions in the real or complex domain** to algebraic equations as well as to trancendental equations˛  **Distinction between genericity and completness does not make sense in the Integers**, an example provided below.

> ```
> Solve[expr,vars] assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in 
> inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex.
> We have the same issue with Reduce[expr,vars].
> ```

### Example :  `Solve` cannot find solutions in the real domain

Consider a simple symbolic case in the real domain where `Solve` does not work even with  `MaxExtraConditions -> All` :

```
Solve[ x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition r ∈ Reals, the solution set
> contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {}
> ```

```
Reduce[ x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> r ∈ Reals && ((x == -Sqrt[r^2] && y == 0) ||
> (-Sqrt[r^2] < x < Sqrt[r^2] && -Sqrt[r^2 - x^2] <= y <= Sqrt[r^2 - x^2]) || 
> (x == Sqrt[r^2] && y == 0))
> ```

We have found none solutions with `Solve`. We should remember that we can find instances in the real domain with :

```
fi = FindInstance[ x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}, 5]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 83/84, y -> 31/18}, {x -> 3, y -> 0}, {x -> 83/84, y -> (13 Sqrt[335])/84}, 
>  {x -> 5/28, y -> -(Sqrt[7031]/28)}, {x -> 37/21, y -> (10 Sqrt[26])/21}}
> ```

However for the same inequality we can find all solutions with `Solve` in the integers.

### Example :  `Solve` provides solutions in the integer domain

```
s = {x, y} /. Solve[ x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}, Integers];
r = (List @@@ List @@ Reduce[ x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}, Integers])[[All, All, 2]]
r == s
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Here the blue region represents solutions described by `Reduce` while the red points on the left plot are instances found with `FindInstance` in the real domain, whereas on the right plot there are all solutions found by `Solve` in the `Integers` :

```
GraphicsRow[{ RegionPlot[ x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                          Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[fi[[All, All, 2]]]}], 
              RegionPlot[ x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                          Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[s]}]}]
```

[image]

### Example :  Genericity can be advantageous for symbolic transcendental equations

Genericity of `Solve` output sometimes can be advantageous, e.g. compare

```
Solve[ x^c == 5, x]
```

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be 
> found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {{x -> 5^(1/c)}}
> ```

`Solve` yields this solution immediately, while `Reduce` after `~ 10` seconds yields a huge boolean formula, here is a little part of it :

```
Reduce[ x^c == 5, x][[3, 2]]
```

> ```
> C[1] <= -1 && (2 π  C[1] - Sqrt[4 π ^2 C[1]^2 + Log[5]^2])/( 2 π ) < Re[c] < 2 C[1] && 
> Im[c] <= (-Log[5] - Sqrt[ Log[5]^2 + 8 π ^2 C[1] Re[c] - 4 π ^2 Re[c]^2])/(2 π ) && 
> x == E^((2 I π  C[1] + Log[5])/c)
> ```

There are another examples where we would rather use `Reduce` rather than `Solve` with specification `MaxExtraConditions -> All` because a list of replacement rules cannot express the full solution unlike a boolean form.

### Example :  `Solve` cannot find the complete solution set

Even with `MaxExtraConditions -> All` option `Solve` sometimes fails which may be seen when we work e.g. with real variables, e.g. :

```
Normal @ Solve[ a x^2 == c && b x^3 == d, x, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition d == 0 && b== 0 &&
> c == 0 && a == 0, 
> the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete 
> solution information. >>
>
> {{x -> 0}, {x -> -Sqrt[(c/a)]}, {x -> Sqrt[c/a]}, {x -> Root[-d + b #1^3 &, 1]}}
> ```

We have used here `Normal` to get rid of `ConditionalExpressions`.

```
 Reduce[ a x^2 == c && b x^3 == d, x, Reals]
```

[image]

For a nice discussion of these topics see this presentation **Getting the Most from Algebraic Solvers in Mathematica** by Adam Strzeboński during [Wolfram Technology Conference 2011](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/videos.html).

### Example : Further issues

`Solve` yields exlicit formulae for the solutions (in terms of radicals) to equations whenever it is possible (it is always possible for univariate algebraic (polynomial) equations up to the order four). For more detailed discussion see e.g. : [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).

You can find more specific differences examining carefully this :

```
Options /@ {Reduce, Solve} // Column
```

> ```
> { Backsubstitution -> False, Cubics -> False, GeneratedParameters -> C,
>   Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> False, 
>   WorkingPrecision -> Infinity}
> { Cubics -> True, GeneratedParameters -> C, InverseFunctions -> Automatic, 
>   MaxExtraConditions -> 0, Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> True, 
>   VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity }
> ```

And even more systematic discussion of the differences might include `SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]`. For some sketches of their usage take a look at this reference [Real Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RealPolynomialSystems.html).

```
SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"] // Short[#, 5] &
```

> ```
> { "ReduceOptions" -> {"ADDSolveBound" -> 8, "AlgebraicNumberOutput" -> True, 
>   "BDDEliminate" -> Automatic, "BooleanInstanceMethod" -> Automatic, <<21>>, 
>   "UseNestedRoots" -> Automatic, "UseOldReduce" -> False,
>   "UseTranscendentalRoots" -> Automatic, "UseTranscendentalSolve" -> True}}
> ```

These issues could be systematically discussed only with concrete examples, so that the main question has to be investigated on a case-by-case basis. See e.g. [Solving/Reducing equations in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003) for a discussion of `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints`.

**Edit**

Another answer by Itai Seggev says that by specifying `Method -> Reduce` in `Solve`, `Solve` will use `Reduce` behind the scenes to produce an answer. That is not quite true. 
Here is an example : [Solve with Method -> Reduce gives a different result than Reduce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/solve-with-method-reduce-gives-a-different-result-than-reduce).

Another statement therein not precise or incorrect is :

"`Reduce` can deal with the following logical conjunction of inequalities, while `Solve` cannot."

**Solve works well with logical conjunction of inequalities** (see e.g. [Solve an equation in $\mathbb{R}^+$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)), let's slightly modify the system :

```
Solve[ x^2 < 1 && Sin[x] == Cos[x], x]
Reduce[ x^2 < 1 && Sin[x] == Cos[x], x]
Reduce[x^2 < 1 && Sin[x] < Cos[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}} 
>  x == -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]
>  -1 < x < -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]
> ```

whereas the issue here is just mentioned above that `the solution set contains a full-dimensional component` (in the real domain). 
For comparison let's see how it works in the integer domain :

```
Solve[ x^2 < 2 && Sin[x] < Cos[x], x, Integers]
Reduce[ x^2 < 2 && Sin[x] < Cos[x], x, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -1}, {x -> 0}}
>  x == -1 || x == 0
> ```

Comment: I don't know how I missed this answer until today, but a hearty +1.  Nice presentation. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I guess I still could improve this answer since a few important details I have in mind to add.

Answer (score 57):

Since version 8, `Solve` and `Reduce` share a great deal of code.  In fact, by Specifying `Method -> Reduce` in `Solve`, `Solve` will use `Reduce` behind the scenes to produce an answer. Off the top of my head, the key differences are as follows:

1) `Reduce` simplifies logical statements, while `Solve` solves equations. This means that given a logical statement (equations, inequalities or quantified statements), `Reduce` will attempt to give you an equivalent, but simpler, statement. For equations, these statements can often directly be solutions, but are still expression as logical expressions like `x==0`.  `Solve`, on the other hand, tries to give you solutions, so it returns a list of replacement rules like `x -> 0` which you can substitute back into your equation to verify its correctness.

*Simple example:* `Reduce` can deal with the following logical conjunction of inequalities, while `Solve` cannot.

```
Reduce[x^2 < 1 && Sin[x] < Cos[x], x]
(* Out: -1 < x < -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] *)
```

2) By default, `Solve` will only give you answers which are generically correct, meaning they don't rely on special values of parameters and may not be completely equivalent to the original equations.  `Reduce`, on the other hand, does not do any transformations which might cause the logical statement to be changed or solutions to be missed.

*Simple example:* `Reduce` considers the possibility that the parameter `a` is zero, while `Solve` does not.

```
Solve[a*x == 0, x]
(* Out: {{x -> 0}} *)

Reduce[a*x == 0, x]
(* Out: a == 0 || x == 0 *)
```

3) `Solve` tends to be less thorough than `Reduce` in order to return an answer faster (somewhat like `Simplify` vs. `FullSimplify`).

Comment: This is a nice answer. Could you please give an example for point 2 on this part: "[...] *may not be completely equivalent to the original equations*"?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I added simple examples for both points 1 and 2.  Of course, Itai, is free to change or modify those, but I do think some example is helpful.

Comment: Interestingly, `Reduce` and `Solve` work even without variable specification and in this case may return identical answers: `Reduce[a*x == 0]`, `Solve[a*x == 0]`.