# All possible solutions to the Matrix Equation (free variables appearing)

Tags: matrix, equation-solving

I am attempting to solve a system of linear equations using `LinearSolve[]` . In my case, the number of unknowns are more than constraints. I learnt that LinearSolve does not give me all solutions. However, I am also unable to use `Solve[]` to get all possible solutions.

Here is my example:

```
InpMatrix={
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{15,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{90,48,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{270,216,144,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{405,432,432,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{243,324,432,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{16,0,0,0,0,0,256,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,-16,-16,-16,47104,1024,0,0,0,0}
};

synd={{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{256},{1024}};

In[217]:= sol = LinearSolve[InpMatrix, synd]

Out[217]= {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {-45}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
```

However, the solution I am looking for should be:

```
{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {-45}, {0}, {30}, {15}, {0}}
```

Hence I tried to use `Solve[]` in the following way:

```
Solve[InpMatrix.var == synd, var]
```

But it gives me an error saying:

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

 Solve[{
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{15, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{90, 48, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{270, 216, 144, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{405, 432, 432, 0, 16, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{243, 324, 432, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, -16, -16, -16, 47104, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}.var == {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {256}, {1024}}, var]
```

Could anyone kindly help me with correctly using `Solve[]` or any other functionality that yields all posible solutions ? Preferably I would general solution, a symbolic form with free variables.

Comment: The "solution you are looking for" clearly is not a solution: when you left-multiply it by `InpMatrix`, you do not obtain `synd`.  Have you perhaps mixed up the roles of the solution and `synd`?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, but it doesn't seem to me that `{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {-45}, {0}, {30}, {15}, {0}}` isn't a solution. Try this if you wish: `InpMatrix.{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {-45}, {0}, {30}, {15}, {0}} == synd` . It gives `True` .

Comment: You're right; I tried exactly that but introduced a typo.  I stand corrected.  Have you looked into `NullSpace`?  It can be used to produce all solutions to `LinearSolve` once you have a single one.  *E.g.*, test it with `InpMatrix.({0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -45, 0, 0, 0, 
    0} + {x1, x2, x3, x4}.NullSpace[InpMatrix])`  Notice that the output of `NullSpace` shows in this case that you can freely vary the last four coefficients.

Comment: Check the documentation for Solve? It wants an explicit list of variables. Coding error here, so too localized seems reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By pen-and-paper, the solution, consisting of a column vector defined by $\{x_1, ... x_{12}\}$, has $x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}, x_{12}$ as free parameters, and the following equations:
$$
16 x_1 + 256 x_7 = 256
$$
$$
-16(x_4+x_5+x_6)+47104x_7 + 1024 x_8 = 1024
$$
There are also 6 other equations (all of which have zero $x_7$ and $x_8$ terms), and all of those equations are homogenous. Thus, all values of $x_1, ... x_6$ are constrained to `0` and we are left with a system where there exists only one solution, the one that, MMA's `LinearSolve` provided, $x_7 = 1$ and $x_8 = -45$.

I naievly thought that `MaxExtraConditions` would give all the solutions in `Solve`, but it did not because the dot multiplication in MMA creates 8 equations, not 12, and `Solve` therefore ignores the last four.

Nonetheless, for the solution $x_s = x_p + x_n$, `Solve` still finds the particular solution for $A.x_p = b$.

Adding the parameterized `NullSpace` gives the full answer:

```
sol = First@
 Block[{var = Array[x, Length@First@InpMatrix]}, 
  Solve[InpMatrix.List /@ 
    var == {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {256}, {1024}}, var, 
   MaxExtraConditions -> All]];
full = Array[x, Length[First@InpMatrix]] /. sol
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -45, x[9], x[10], x[11], x[12]} *)
```

And your four free parameters are $x_9, ... x_{12}$.

In fact, by using the form `Array[x, Length[First@InpMatrix]] /. sol`, all fixed parameters are given their appropriate values and all free parameters (which either show up and are replaced appropriately by the rules from `Solve` or stay in their `x[_]` form are likewise given. Thus, `full` represents the complete ($x_p + x_n$) solution.

Comment: Your application of `Solve` gives a set of solutions with *four* free parameters, `x[9]`, `x[10]`, `x[11]`, and `x[12]`. That's the complete set of all solutions.

Comment: Oh. My mistake. I see what my issue is. The rank is 8, and there in fact only is four free parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation page  explicitely says :

> ```
> For underdetermined systems,  LinearSolve will return one of the possible solutions;
> Solve will return a general solution.
> ```

So in our case `LinearSolve` yields only one solution, even though there are infinitely many of them.

With `Solve` thre are two issues :

- `Solve` interprets `var` as a number, not just a vector, that's why you couldn't get the correct solution.
- working with `Solve` we encounter the full dimensional component problem (related issues you could find here : [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)) because of the null space (see `NullSpace`) of `InpMatrix` is a linear (vector) `4`-dimensional subspace of the domain vector space.

Concerning the first issue we can see e.g. adding this option `MaxExtraConditions -> All`  :

```
Solve[ InpMatrix.var == synd, var, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

compare it with e.g. the output of

```
Solve[ InpMatrix.var == synd, var]
```

To resolve the problem one should set e.g. :

```
var = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12};
```

We get the warning exactly because of the full component problem, even with `MaxExtraConditions -> All` :

```
var /. Solve[ InpMatrix.var == synd, var, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -45, a9, a10, a11, a12}}
> ```

So this vector `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -45, 0, 30, 15, 0}` certainly belongs to the formal space expressed with this solution `{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -45, a9, a10, a11, a12}}` even though it is a full-dimensional (4-dimentional affine subspace), not just some exceptional points (`12`-dimensional vectors) in it. The reason of the warning is that replacement rules basically cannot represent  full-dimensional components, and this is the case here. It is perfectly appropriate in general even though it is not harmful here. To emphasize the issue see :

```
Solve[ Floor[x] == 2, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component;
> use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {{}}
> ```

of course this works well :

```
Reduce[ Floor[x] == 2, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> 2 <= x < 3
> ```

The warning above suggest to use `Reduce` because boolean formulae are capable to express full-dimensional componets, so here is also another possibility, ensuring there is only  one solution (expressing infinitely many ones since `a9, a10, a11, a12` need not be specified) :

```
Reduce[ InpMatrix.var == synd, var]
```

> ```
> a1 == 0 && a2 == 0 && a3 == 0 && a4 == 0 && a5 == 0 && a6 == 0 && a7 == 1 && a8 == -45
> ```

Moreover you might find useful `NullSpace` :

```
NullSpace[InpMatrix]
```

> ```
>  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

This means that every vector of the form `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d}` yields `0` (in the eight-dimensional target vector space) if one acts on it with `InpMatrix`, i.e.

```
InpMatrix.{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I am more confused. How come Solve[] is saying there are no solutions ? Clearly by inspection we can see that there is atleast one solution. Isn't it so? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Artes but the vector `{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-45,0,0,0,0}` _does_ give `synd`... That is, `synd` is not in the null space of `InpMatrix`.

Comment: @Artes,VF1 Yes, and so is this too a solution: `{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {-45}, {0}, {30}, {15}, {0}}` . Sure I agree with you that there are no solutions of the type `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d}` . My problem is to find all possible solutions, not necessarily of the particular type which you had mentioned. I am not sure how useful it would be to find the `NullSpace[]` of `InpMatrix` because the vector on the Right Side of the Matrix Equation is not a zero vector.

Comment: @VF1 Thanks for the feedback, I've just corrected it.

Comment: @PavithranIyer Now I've just included explaining to all issues you encounter in the problem.

Comment: Pavithran, the null space is critical to finding all solutions, because *every* solution can be obtained as any particular solution (where the RHS is not necessary zero) plus some element of the null space.  If this is not perfectly clear, please consult any textbook on linear algebra.

Comment: @Artes @whuber Could you still please address the issue that `MaxExtraConditions` is not parametrizing the particular solution, as I brought up in my answer/comment? Should I make that its own question (because now I am interested myself)?

Comment: @VF1 By not stipulating any values for `x[9]` through `x[12]`, Solve really *is* returning all solutions. Compare its output where the null space is a little more complicated to represent, as in `m = Array[1 &, {3, 3}];
Block[{var = Array[x, Last[Dimensions[m]]]}, 
 Solve[m.var == {0, 0, 0}, var]]`. Even *without* `MaxExtraConditions`, and despite issuing a warning, `Solve` has obtained all solutions.

Comment: @VF1 I added the full explanation of the problem, see  the edit. Namely `MaxExtraCondition->All` is not neccesary here, nonetheless it is more reliable to add it to avoid possible problems. Just  one gets the general solution with `Solve` (even without any options) which (in this case) is the full symbolic solution as well.