# Inequalities with assumptions and constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm using Mathematica 8

I've been searching the net without luck for this specific solutions:

Suppose I have an inequality f(x;M,m)>0 where I KNOW that M>4m and m>0. How can I let *Mathematica* know this so that when solving the inequality using `Reduce` I don't get twenty irrelevant solutions, but instead only solutions where 0<4m

I've used assumptions and so on but without luck, for instance:

```
Assuming[m > 0, Reduce[(x + m)*(x - m) < 0]]
```

Produces;

```
x \[Element] Reals && (m < -Sqrt[x^2] || m > Sqrt[x^2])
```

`m<-Sqrt` is unnecessary here, so why does *Mathematica* write it out? How can we stop it?

Comment: Like `Reduce[{(x + m)*(x - m) < 0, m > 0}]`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip...it works. Also it seems that one can have several constraints by using a simple comma. Thanks man!

Comment: Just fit everything into a list: `Reduce[{equation, inequality1, inequality2, ...}]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the comments already solved the problem, here is an answer with slight additions:

`Assumptions` and the command `Assuming` (which makes assumptions locally), don't affect `Reduce`. A good way to check whether a given command (say `Solve`) is affected by `Assuming` is to look through the `Options` for that function and see if `Assumptions` is among them. If not, then `Assuming` won't work either (at least to my knowledge).

So if you want to use `Reduce` inside `Assuming` and make sure that `Reduce` obeys the assumptions, you could include them in the list of expressions as follows:

```
Assuming[m > 0, Reduce[{$Assumptions, (x + m)*(x - m) < 0}]]

(* ==> m > 0 && -Sqrt[m^2] < x < Sqrt[m^2] *)
```

Here I'm invoking the variable `$Assumptions` in a list together with the inequality that I want `Reduce` to work with.

Comment: I cannot recall seeing that method before. +1