# Use of $Assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I don't really understand the behaviour and the usage of `$Assumption`.
For instance, when I set `$Assumptions = λ > 0`, I expect that

```
TrueQ[λ > 0]
```

or at least

```
 Reduce[ TrueQ[λ > 0]]
```

return `True`, but both return `False`.

Then I was wondering how to make more assumptions:

```
$Assumptions = λ > 0 && c > 0 && a < 0 && λ ∈ Reals && a ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals && 
    n ∈ Integers && n > 0
```

Now, if I try to Reduce the following,

```
Reduce[Product[1 + (λ + c)/f[x],x] <= (a ((λ + c)/λ))^n]
```

The condition  `(a (c + λ))/λ)^n ∈ Reals` is not obvious, and

```
TrueQ[((a (c + λ))/λ)^n ∈ Reals]
(* False *)
```

I read the documentation but I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Nasser Why? I plan to use many expression using the same assumptions, so I decided to assume them globally...

Comment: Only a small number of _Mathematica_ functions make use of assumptions. You need to read this [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html), which gives the list and will give you a better understanding of when and how _Mathematica_ makes use of assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you misunderstood the usage of [`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrueQ.html). It doesn't make use of assumptions, and [neither does `Reduce`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23213/245). Replace it by `Simplify` everywhere to make use of the `$Assumptions`:

```
$Assumptions = λ > 0

(* ==> λ > 0 *)

Simplify[λ > 0]

(* ==> True *)

$Assumptions = λ > 0 && c > 0 && 
  a < 0 && λ \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals && 
  c \[Element] Reals && n \[Element] Integers && n > 0;

Simplify[((a (c + λ))/λ)^n \[Element] Reals]

(* ==> True *)
```

The larger expression

```
Reduce[Product[1 + (λ + c)/f[x],x] <= (a ((λ + c)/λ))^n]
```

can't be simplified because neither `f[x]` nor `n` on the left-hand side of the equation are defined. `n` is probably meant to be the number of terms in the product, but you're using `Product` without limits.