# Mathematica does not respect tensor order?

Tags: matrix, assumptions, tensors

I'm trying to verify an identity involving symmetric traceless tensors over the reals. What I tried was:

```
In[11]:= $Assumptions = d \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
Out[11]= d \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
In[24]:= dd = d - Tr[d] IdentityMatrix[3]/3
Out[24]= {{d - Tr[d]/3, d, d}, {d, d - Tr[d]/3, d}, {d, d,d - Tr[d]/3}}
```

I think the output in 24 is assuming that d is now a scalar. That gets me into trouble later when I tried to compute outer products of dd and use TensorReduce. For example

```
lh = TensorReduce[TensorContract[dd\[TensorProduct]dd, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]]
TensorDimensions::fscl: Nonscalar expression d encountered as an argument of numeric function Power. >>
TensorDimensions::inhom: Inhomogeneous dimensions in sum d-Tr[d]/3. >>
```

Why is this not working, and what is the right way to do computations on traceless matrices?
Sune

Comment: Related: [Inequalities with assumptions and constraints](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23165/245)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue**

The main issue here is you can't add symbolic tensors with explicit tensors. In your example, `d` is a symbolic tensor, but `IdentityMatrix[3]` is an explicit tensor. Note what happens when you add them:

```
$Assumptions = Element[d, Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1,2}]]];

d + IdentityMatrix[3]
```

> {{1 + d, d, d}, {d, 1 + d, d}, {d, d, 1 + d}}

The [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) causes `d` to be added to all of the matrix elements of `IdentityMatrix[3]`.

**Symbolic identity matrix**

Instead of using the explicit tensor `IdentityMatrix[3]`, you can use either `IdentityMatrix[n]` or `Inactive[IdentityMatrix]`[3]. For example:

```
d + IdentityMatrix[n]
d + Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]
```

> d + IdentityMatrix[n]
>
> d + Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]

In both cases no explicit matrix is generated. Now, for your example, it is better to use `Inactive[IdentityMatrix]`[3] so that dimensions match up. If you had used `Element[d, Matrices[{n, n}]]` instead, you could use `IdentityMatrix[n]`. So:

```
dd = d - Tr[d] Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]/3;

TensorReduce @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[dd, dd], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[d, d], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] - 
>    2/3 TensorContract[
>      TensorProduct[d, Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] Tr[
>      d] + 1/9 TensorContract[
>      TensorProduct[Inactive[IdentityMatrix][
>        3], Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]], {{1, 3}, {2, 
>        4}}] Tr[d]^2

Unfortunately, at the present time, [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) doesn't know what to do with these "symbolic" identity tensors. Therefore, we will need to help things along.

**`` SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor ``**

One possibility is to make use of the internal symbol `` SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor ``. When a single such symbol is involved in a tensor contraction, then [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) will properly simplify the tensor product. Here is an example:

```
tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[d, Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];
tensor /. Inactive[IdentityMatrix] -> SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor
```

> TensorContract[d, {{1, 2}}]

On the other hand, if the [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) contains a "symbolic" identity tensor (i.e., `Inactive[IdentityMatrix]`[3] or `IdentityMatrix[n]`) that is not contracted, then [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) produces an error:

```
tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[d, Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3], d], {{1, 5}}];
tensor /. Inactive[IdentityMatrix] -> SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor
```

> Part::pkspec1: The expression {SymbolicTensors`SymbolicTensorsDump`i} cannot be used as a part specification.
>
> ...

where I've suppressed most of the output. Similarly, if the [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) contains multiple "symbolic" identity tensors, even if they are all contracted, [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) still produces an error:

```
tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3], Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]], {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}];
tensor /. Inactive[IdentityMatrix] -> SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor
```

> Part::partw: Part {2,3} of {3[1,1],2[1,2]} does not exist.
>
> ...

So, what is needed is a method to find "symbolic" identity tensors that are being contracted, and one at a time, replace those tensors with `` SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor ``.

**IdentityReduce**

*Update - The paclet now lives on GitHub, and can be installed using:*

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Here is a function that does this (soon to be a part of a `TensorSimplify` package I will be putting on GitHub):

```
IdentityReduce[expr_] := expr /. TensorContract -> ir

ir[t_TensorProduct, i_] := Module[{indices, imIndices, ids, dummy},
    indices = tensorIndices[t];
    If[indices === $Failed, Return[TensorContract[t, i]]];
    imIndices = Position[
        Replace[t, Inactive[IdentityMatrix][n_] -> dummy[n], {1}],
        IdentityMatrix | dummy,
        {2}
    ];
    ids = Pick[
        imIndices,
        IntersectingQ[Flatten[i],indices[#]]& /@ imIndices[[All,1]]
    ];
    If[ids==={},
        TensorContract[t,i],
        TensorContract[ReplacePart[t, ids[[1]]->SymbolicTensors`IdentityTensor],i] /. TensorContract->ir
    ]
]

ir[(Inactive[IdentityMatrix] | IdentityMatrix)[n_], {{1,2}}]=n;
ir[o_, i_]:=TensorContract[o,i]

tensorIndices[Verbatim[TensorProduct][t__]] := With[{r=Accumulate @* Map[TensorRank] @ {1,t}},
    If[MatchQ[r, {__Integer}],
        Association @ Thread @ Rule[
            Range@Length[{t}], 
            Range[1+Most[r], Rest[r]]
        ],
        $Failed
    ]
]
```

Let's try the OP example again:

```
e = TensorReduce @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[dd, dd], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];
IdentityReduce @ e
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[d, d], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] - 
>    2/3 TensorContract[d, {{1, 2}}] Tr[d] + Tr[d]^2/3

Notice how the symbolic identity tensors have been resolved. One can perform one final step, converting all [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) objects to [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot)/[`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) (if possible) using my [`FromTensor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155631/45431) function:

```
FromTensor @ IdentityReduce @ e
```

> -(1/3) Tr[d]^2 + Tr[Transpose[d].d]

It is possible to use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) on this expression, but it produces a result using `Tr[MatrixPower[d, 2]]` instead of `Tr[d.d]`, so I won't do so.

Answer (score 6):

Assumptions are not used in normal evaluation, but only in certain functions like `Simplify`. Another, simpler example:

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = x \[Element] Reals

Out[1]= x \[Element] Reals

In[2]:= Conjugate[x]

Out[2]= Conjugate[x]

In[3]:= Simplify[%]

Out[3]= x
```

You see, during normal evaluation Mathematica doesn't recognize that `x` is supposed to be real, only during `Simplify`.

You can identify the functions which take `$Assumptions` into account by the fact that they also accept an option `Assumption`. On Mathematica 8, using

```
Select[Names["System`*"],Options[Symbol@#,Assumptions]!={}&]
```

I get the following list:

- `ContinuedFractionK`
- `Convolve`
- `DifferenceDelta`
- `DifferenceRootReduce`
- `DifferentialRootReduce`
- `DirichletTransform`
- `DiscreteConvolve`
- `DiscreteRatio`
- `DiscreteShift`
- `Expectation`
- `ExpectedValue`
- `ExponentialGeneratingFunction`
- `FinancialBond`
- `FourierCoefficient`
- `FourierCosCoefficient`
- `FourierCosSeries`
- `FourierCosTransform`
- `FourierSequenceTransform`
- `FourierSeries`
- `FourierSinCoefficient`
- `FourierSinSeries`
- `FourierSinTransform`
- `FourierTransform`
- `FourierTrigSeries`
- `FullSimplify`
- `FunctionExpand`
- `GeneratingFunction`
- `Integrate`
- `InverseFourierCosTransform`
- `InverseFourierSequenceTransform`
- `InverseFourierSinTransform`
- `InverseFourierTransform`
- `InverseZTransform`
- `LaplaceTransform`
- `Limit`
- `PiecewiseExpand`
- `PossibleZeroQ`
- `PowerExpand`
- `Probability`
- `ProbabilityDistribution`
- `Product`
- `Refine`
- `Residue`
- `Series`
- `SeriesCoefficient`
- `Simplify`
- `Sum`
- `SumConvergence`
- `TimeValue`
- `ToRadicals`
- `TransformedDistribution`
- `ZTransform`

Comment: To be more precise, `$Assumptions` only works on functions with `Assumptions` option :)

Comment: @xzczd: I already suspected that, but wasn't quite sure, so I didn't include that. But now that you say so, I think it can be safely included. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks - got it. So perhaps the only way of approaching my problem would be to define SymmetrizedArrays with proper symmetries and then subtract the trace explicitly?

Comment: I don't have experience with `SymmetrizedArray` (it's a Mathematica 9 feature, and I only have access to Mathematica 8), so I cannot tell you whether that would be the correct or best approach. The problem here is that Mathematica treats all unbound variables as scalars during evaluation, and there's AFAIK no way to override that behaviour for specific variables.

Comment: The OP is using M9+, and in M9+ TensorReduce accepts the Assumptions option. So, the OP is correct in assuming that his $Assumptions are used during TensorReduce.