# Function to convert TensorContract[_TensorProduct, indices] into equivalent Dot + Tr version

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

Mathematica can use either [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) to represent some tensors, or [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct). I believe that the [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representation, while verbose, is more powerful for a couple reasons:

1. It can represent a wider variety of tensors, e.g., `TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, b], {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}]` where `a` and `b` are rank 3 tensors doesn't have an equivalent [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) representation (at least, I can't think of one).
2. [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) can in some cases reduce pure [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) expressions better than the equivalent [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) expressions.

Because of the above, it would be convenient to have a function that converted a [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) representation into a [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representation. Another reason why it would be nice to have such a function is that [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) of a pure [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) often works much better than [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) of a mixture of a [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) and [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representation.

**Pure vs mixed**

Here is an example where [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) works better with pure [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) representations instead of mixed representations:

```
TensorReduce[
    r.R - TensorContract[TensorProduct[R, r], {{1, 2}}],
    Assumptions -> (r|R) \[Element] Vectors[3]
]

TensorReduce[
    TensorContract[TensorProduct[r, R], {{1, 2}}] - TensorContract[TensorProduct[R, r], {{1, 2}}],
    Assumptions -> (r|R) \[Element] Vectors[3]
]
```

> r.R - TensorContract[r[TensorProduct]R, {{1, 2}}]
>
> 0

**ToTensor**

The following function can be used to convert at [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) representation into a [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representation:

```
ToTensor[expr_] := expr /. {Dot->dot, Tr->tr}

dot[a__] := With[{indices = Accumulate@Map[TensorRank]@{a}},
    TensorContract[TensorProduct[a], {#, # + 1} & /@ Most[indices]]
]

tr[a_] /; TensorRank[a] == 2 := TensorContract[a, {{1, 2}}]
tr[a_, Plus, 2] := TensorContract[a, {{1, 2}}]
tr[a___] := Tr[a]
```

**FromTensor**

It would be nice to have a function that converts a [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representation into a [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) representation, if possible. Let's call such a function `FromTensor`. Then, a `TensorSimplify` function that does something like `FromTensor @ TensorReduce @ ToTensor @ expr` could be defined that is as powerful as a simple [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce), but allows one to work with [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) or mixed representations.

**Examples**

The kinds of [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) + [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) representations that should be converted into a [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) + [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) representation include at least the following, where `a` and `b` are vectors, and `m` and `n` are matrices:

1. `Tr[m.n]` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[m, n], {{1, 4}, {2,3}}]`
2. `m.n` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[m, n], {{2, 3}}]`
3. `a.m.n` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, m, n], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`
4. `a.m.n.b` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, m, n, b], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]`

Some other similar examples:

1. `a.Transpose[n].Transpose[m]` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, m, n], {{1, 5}, {4, 3}}]`
2. `Tr[Transpose[m].n]` ⇔ `TensorContract[TensorProduct[m, n], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]`

There may be other equivalent representations.

So, my question is, can somebody write such a `FromTensor` function?

*(I have written such a function, but I am unhappy with it. I'm hopeful that someone can write a better one. I will post my version as an answer at some point, but for now I'm curious what other independent answers are possible)*

Comment: +1 as such conversions are direly needed for performance reasons when dealing with large numerical high rank tensors. `TensorContract` + `TensorProduct` is very expressive but as the `TensorProduct` is generated first, it is also extremely memory hungry.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

*I have put the package on GitHub. One can install the paclet using:*

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

*and then load it with*

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

*The package includes 4 functions. One (`FromTensor`) is described below. The other three are `ToTensor`, `IdentityReduce` and `TensorSimplify`. `ToTensor` converts `Dot`/`Tr` to `TensorContract` objects, `IdentityReduce` simplifies identity tensors (typically inactive `IdentityMatrix` objects) and `TensorSimplify` converts to `TensorContract` objects, then uses both `TensorReduce` and `IdentityReduce`.*

As promised, I will present my current code for `FromTensor`. This function will shortly be part of a package on GitHub, augmented with code to handle symbolic identity tensors.

```
FromTensor[expr_] := expr /. TensorContract->tc

tc[a_TensorProduct, i_] := Module[{res = itc[a, i]},
    res /; res =!= $Failed
]
tc[a_, {{1, 2}}] /; TensorRank[a] == 2 := Tr[Replace[a, (Transpose|TensorTranspose)[m_, {2, 1} | PatternSequence[]]-> m]]
tc[a__] := TensorContract[a]

itc[a_TensorProduct, i_] := Module[
    {indices, rnk, s=0, ends, g, nodes, info, tlist, res},
    indices = tensorIndices[a];
    rnk = TensorRank @ TensorContract[a,i];

    (* 
     * Determine ends of the contraction chain.
     * For Tr, remove one set of indices, and find contraction 
     * chain of remaining indices
     *)

    ends = Switch[{rnk, Sort@Tally[Length/@indices]},
        {0, {{2,_}}}, Complement[Range@TensorRank[a], Flatten@Most@i],
        {2, {{2,_}}}, Complement[Range@TensorRank[a],Flatten@i],
        {1, {{1,1},{2,_}}}, {0, First@Complement[Range@TensorRank[a],Flatten@i]},
        {0, {{1,2},{2,_}|PatternSequence[]}}, {0,-1},
        _,Return[$Failed]
    ];

    (* find contraction chain. Augment vectors with 0 | -1 so that each node is a pair *)
    g = FindPath[
            Graph @ Join[
            Cases[indices, p:{_,_} :> UndirectedEdge@@p],
            Cases[indices,{p_} :> UndirectedEdge[s--, p]],
            UndirectedEdge @@@ i
        ],
        First@ends,
        Last@ends,
        {2 (Length[i] - Boole[rnk == 0 && Min[ends]>0])+ 1}
    ];
    (* unable to find a single contraction containing all tensors *)
    If[g === {}, Return[$Failed, Module]];

    (* find node (tensor) indices in the contraction chain *)
    nodes = DeleteCases[Partition[First@g, 2, 2], 0|-1, Infinity];

    (* determine tensors corresponding to indices, and whether to transpose tensor *)
    info=Table[
        Query[Select[MemberQ[n]], MatchQ[{n,___}]][indices],
        {n, nodes[[All,1]]}
    ];

    (* standardize Transpose *)
    tlist = Replace[
        List@@a,
        (TensorTranspose | Transpose)[m_, {2, 1}] -> Transpose[m],
        {1}
    ]; 

    (* create equivalent Dot product *)
    res = Dot @@ MapThread[
        If[#2, #1, Transpose[#1]]&,
        {
            tlist[[Flatten@Keys[info]]],
            Flatten@Values[info]
        }
    ];
    res = Replace[res, Transpose[Transpose[m_]] :> m, {1}];

    (* For 0-rank outputs, determine whether the normal or "transposed" version has fewer Transpose's *)
    Which[
        rnk > 0,
        res,

        TensorRank[res] > 0,
        If[Count[res, _Transpose] > Length[a]/2,
            Tr @ Replace[Reverse[res], {Transpose[m_]:>m, m_:>Transpose[m]}, {1}],
            Tr @ res
        ],

        Count[res,_Transpose] > Length[a]/2-1,
        res = Reverse[res];
        res[[2 ;; -2]] = Replace[List @@ res[[2 ;; -2]], {Transpose[m_]:>m, m_:>Transpose[m]}, {1}];
        res,

        True,
        res
    ]
]

(* tensorIndices returns a list of node -> indices rules *)
tensorIndices[Verbatim[TensorProduct][t__]] := With[{r=Accumulate @* Map[TensorRank] @ {1,t}},
    If[MatchQ[r, {__Integer}],
        Association @ Thread @ Rule[
            Range@Length[{t}], 
            Range[1+Most[r], Rest[r]]
        ],
        $Failed
    ]
]
```

Here are some examples of `FromTensor` usage:

```
$Assumptions = Element[a|b, Vectors[n]] && Element[M|T|A|B, Matrices[{n,n}]];

FromTensor @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[M,T,Transpose[A],B], {{1,4},{3,6},{5,7},{8,2}}]
FromTensor @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,M,T], {{1,3},{2,4}}]
FromTensor @ TensorContract[M, {{1,2}}]
FromTensor @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[M,T], {{2,3}}]
FromTensor @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,b], {{1,2}}]
FromTensor @ TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,Transpose[M],T,b], {{1,3}, {2,5}, {4,6}}]
```

> Tr[Transpose[A].T.M.Transpose[B]]
>
> a.Transpose[M].T
>
> Tr[M]
>
> M.T
>
> a.b
>
> a.M.Transpose[T].b

One can use random inputs to test `FromTensor`. For example, here is a list of rules:

```
rules = {
    A -> RandomReal[1, {3,3}],
    B -> RandomReal[1, {3,3}],
    M -> RandomReal[1, {3,3}],
    T -> RandomReal[1, {3,3}],
    a -> RandomReal[1, 3],
    b -> RandomReal[1, 3]
};
```

And here are tests of some of the previous examples:

```
tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[M,T,Transpose[A],B], {{1,4},{3,6},{5,7},{8,2}}];
tensor /. rules
FromTensor @ tensor /. rules

tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,M,T], {{1,3},{2,4}}];
tensor /. rules
FromTensor @ tensor /. rules

tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,Transpose[M],T,b], {{1,3}, {2,5}, {4,6}}];
tensor /. rules
FromTensor @ tensor /. rules
```

> 4.17922
>
> 4.17922
>
> {1.4244, 0.45804, 1.00372}
>
> {1.4244, 0.45804, 1.00372}
>
> 2.40798
>
> 2.40798

If the [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) object consists of multiple distinct contractions, e.g., `TensorContract[TensorProduct[M, T], {{1,2}, {3,4}}]`, then `FromTensor` will not perform a conversion. In this case, one should use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) first. Here is an example:

```
tensor = TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,M,T],{{1,3},{4,5}}];

FromTensor @ tensor
FromTensor @ TensorReduce @ tensor
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, M, T], {{1, 3}, {4, 5}}]
>
> a.Transpose[M] Tr[T]

This version of `FromTensor` doesn't work with individual tensors higher than rank 2.

Comment: When you do get this to GitHub, you should set up a paclet server for all your stuff so the rest of us can use it more easily :) Since [it turns out we can use GitHub for paclets, after all](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155124/38205)

Comment: Would you know why this fails? It includes a matrix build from a vector through $v\cdot v^\top$: `$Assumptions = 
 Element[v, Vectors[d]] && M \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals]`, `M.v.Transpose[v].M // TensorSimplify`. Error is _Permute::lowlen: Required length 1 is smaller than maximum 2 of support of {2,1}._