# Operations on symbolic tensors

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I have recently discovered the set of functions related to symbolic tensors, namely `TensorProduct`, `TensorContract`, `TensorReduce`, etc.

Some of the operations provided were already available, for example `TensorProduct` should correspond to `KroneckerProduct`, while `TensorContract` with the right choice of two indexes should correspond to `Dot`, but it seems that that functions cannot operate together with symbolic tensors.

This is my example:

```
$Assumptions = {
  Element[a, Vectors[3, Reals]],
  Element[b, Vectors[3, Reals]]
  };

TensorProduct[a, b] == KroneckerProduct[a, b] // TensorReduce
(* a\[TensorProduct]b == KroneckerProduct[a, b] *)

TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, b], {1, 2}] == Dot[a, b] // TensorReduce
(* TensorContract[a\[TensorProduct]b, {{1, 2}}] == a . b *)
```

I expected a `True` result from both expressions.

Comment: A simple guess is that `KroneckerProduct ` and `Dot ` are not integrated into the symbolic tensor computations.

Comment: [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) and [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) are only the same for vectors. For example, compare ``Dimensions @ TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],IdentityMatrix[2]]`` to ``Dimensions @ KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],IdentityMatrix[2]]``

Comment: @CarlWoll, thanks, I misunderstood how `KroneckerProduct` is defined, but the question on `Dot` is still valid?

Comment: For Dot, see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155476/45431)

Comment: @CarlWoll thank you