# Cannot symmetrize products involving tensors with specified symmetry?

Tags: tensors, tensortranspose, symmetrize

I am trying to check some manipulations with tensors with Mathematica (13.3 on Windows), but was stuck on an error from TensorTranspose. I isolated my problem to the following simple case:

```
$Assumptions =  b \[Element] Arrays[{3, 3}, Complexes, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
Symmetrize[b, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

which fails with error `TensorTranspose::symmperm: Invalid permutation or symmetry generator {Cycles[{}],2}.`
Obviously this is a silly thing to do in itself - but don't see why it would produce an error. I really wanted to check some contractions of symmetrized products of Kronecker deltas with totally symmetric tensors, and I got the same error as above. So I think if I can understand why this simple example don't work, I will understand the real problem as well.
S

Comment: I think it is related to what I asked 9 years ago (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/mathematica-does-not-respect-tensor-order) but had completely forgotten ;) I guess Mathematica does not use the assumptions in Symmetrize and treats b as a scalar and hence cannot do the requested transpositions.