# Reducing a system of vector equations

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of vector equations. I know this is solvable since I've done it myself by hand (I reduced it to solving the root of a quartic anyway). I'm trying to do it in *Mathematica* because I have another similar one I want to solve that I'm getting the same error for.

```
$Assumptions = (p | q | u | v | a | b) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
    $Assumptions = (t | k) ∈ Reals;
Reduce[{{1/2 a t^2 + u t + p == 1/2 b t^2 + v t + q}, {Norm[a] == k}}, {a, t}];
```

Evaluating this shows:

> Solve::naqs: "{p+(a\t^2)/2+t\ u==q+(b\t^2)/2+t\ v}&&{Norm[a]==k} is
>   not a quantified system of equations and inequalities."

Comment: here, and in your answer, your second `$Assumptions` overwrites the first one.  Sort of moot though because I'm pretty sure `Reduce` cant make any use of the vector assumption.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for mentioning it... both those points answer my other question, which then that brings up the question of how do you solve a system of vector equations?

Comment: Closely related to the futility of `$Assumptions` here : [Inequalities with assumptions and constraints](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23165/245).

Comment: The brute force approach is to express all of your vectors as lists with symbolic components. The results are usually pretty unwieldy however.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if the syntax I used is supposed to work for the set of equations, but if I switch to using && between the equations, it appears to work fine:

```
$Assumptions = (p | q | u | v | a | b) \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]
    $Assumptions = (t | k) \[Element] Reals
Reduce[
 1/2*a*t^2 + u*t + p == 1/2 * b * t^2 + v*t + q &&
  Norm[a] == k, {a, t}, Reals]
```