# find where 3 inequalities are simultaneously greater than zero

Tags: equation-solving

I have 3 functions: `f11[l]`, `f12[l]` and `f13[l]`, and I would like to know for which values of `l` these 3 functions are greater than zero. How do I do it analytically or numerically or graphically in *Mathematica*?
   For some of the functions I want to consider only the real part.

Example:

```
f11[l] = Root[ 54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + 
              (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 1]; 

f12[l] = Root[ 54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + 
              (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 2]; 

f13[l] = Root[ 54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + 
              (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 3];
```

Comment: Just to complement, an example of my functions is:
f11[l]=Root[54 + 
   9 Sqrt[6]
     l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - 
      Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 1];
    f12[l]=Root[54 + 
   9 Sqrt[6]
     l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - 
      Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 2];
    f13[l]=Root[54 + 
   9 Sqrt[6]
     l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 + (-20 - 
      Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 3];

Comment: I tried Solve, of course and nothing. I tried reduce for each of the equations alone and got a resulta that is wrong. hehehehe
I just needed for which values of l all 3 are greater than zero. Even if it is graphically only.

Answer (score 9):

Since all the functions are roots of the same polynomial, a recommended approach uses a definition of one function instead of defining them separately. Thus  I'd rather proceed along this way:

```
f[x_, k_Integer] /; 1 <= k <= 4 := 
  Root[ 54 + 9 Sqrt[6] x + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] x) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] x) #1^2 
           + (-20 - Sqrt[6] x) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, k]
```

This definition (using patterns, see `FullForm[f[x_, k_Integer]]`) allows usage of different symbols unlike yours, e.g. `f11` must be called only with `l`, moreover we have:

```
f11[l] == f[l, 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We restricted `k` to the range `{1, 2, 3, 4}` with `Condition` (shorthand `/;`) because there are `4` roots of your polynomial.

Now, the function you need is `Reduce`, it is very powerful and for these functions there is no need for further search. `Solve` is not appropriate when one is looking for resolving inequalities since it gives (because of the output in terms of replacement rules) :

```
Solve[ Table[ f[x, k] > 0, {k, 4}], x]
```

> ```
>  Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component;
>    use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {{}}
> ```

```
Reduce[ Table[ f[x, k] > 0, {k, 4}], x]
```

> ```
>  x > -Sqrt[6]
> ```

We supplement the symbolic result with a graphics demonstrating how the functions depend on `x`. The main difficulty here is an appropriate choice of `PlotStyle` for every curve in order to provide a clear presentation, their graphs are plotted with dashed lines, while the domain where all the functions are non-negative with a thick magenta line:

```
Plot[ Table[ f[x, k], {k, 4}], {x, -7, 7}, Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Table[
             {Thick, Sequence @@ c}, {c, {{Dashed, Red}, {Dashing[0.02], Cyan}, 
                                           {Dashing[0.03], Blue}, {Dashing[0.02], Green}}}], 
             Epilog -> {Thickness[0.008], Darker @ Magenta, Line[{{-Sqrt[6], 0}, {6.5, 0}}]},
             PlotRange -> {-1.5, 4.5}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.05], 
             PlotLegends -> {"f1(x)", "f2(x)", "f3(x)", "f4(x)"}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

From the plot we can see that we might be interested in the differences `f[x, 2] - f[x, 3]`
 as well as `f[x, 4] - f[x, 3]`:

```
FullSimplify[f[x, 2] - f[x, 3], x >= -3] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Refine[ %, x >= 0]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

```
FullSimplify[ f[x, 4] - f[x, 3], x >= -3] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Refine[%, x < 0]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

Comment: [Plot[{f11[x], f12[x], f13[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTMX.png)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I worked perfectly!

Comment: @Elisa You are welcome, note that you could use `Solve` if you restrict to a bounded range of integers, e.g. `Solve[f11[x] > 0 && f12[x] > 0 && f13[x] > 0 && x < 10, x, Integers]`. For more complete discussion you could look here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129

Answer (score 1):

The following is also useful:

```
f11[l_] := Root[54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 
                + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 1]

f12[l_] := Root[54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2 
                + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 2]

f13[l_] := Root[54 + 9 Sqrt[6] l + (-108 - 15 Sqrt[6] l) #1 + (72 + 7 Sqrt[6] l) #1^2
                + (-20 - Sqrt[6] l) #1^3 + 2 #1^4 &, 3]

Framed@Column[FullSimplify[#@x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]] & /@ {f11, f12, f13}]
```

[image]

And

```
Plot[{f11[x], f12[x], f13[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image: aa]