# Colors for multiple piecewise functions

Tags: color, piecewise

I have the following $3$ piecewise functions, and I would like that `f1`, `f2` and `f3` have $3$ different colours:

```
Plot[ Piecewise[{{{f1, f2,f3}, B < 1/2}, {{f1, f2,f3}, B > 1/2}}], {B, 0, 1}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Besides the answers below this one [find where 3 inequalities are simultaneously greater than zero](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/find-where-3-inequalities-are-simultaneously-greater-than-zero/25062#25062) might be an interesting supplement as well.

Answer (score 8):

To colorize the plot you need the list of piecewices not piecewise of lists. See the following example:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{{x^2, 1}, x < 1}, {{2 - x, x}, x > 1}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[pw, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

You can convert `pw` to the list of piecewices manually or automatically by

```
pw2 = Piecewise /@ Transpose[Thread /@ pw[[1]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[pw2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

---

Alternative to Michael's post-processing method:

```
f1 = B; f2 = B^2; f3 = 1 - B^3;
Module[{n = 0}, 
 Plot[Piecewise[{{{f1, f2, f3}, B < 1/2}, {{f1, f2, f3}, B > 1/2}}], {B, 0, 1}] /. 
  Line[p_] :> {ColorData[1, Ceiling[n += 1/2]], Line[p]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the exact parameters of this problem.  Let's suppose that, for whatever reason, the function comes as `Piecewise` function whose values are triples of real numbers.

---

Then one way is to convert the `Piecewise` function into three `Piecewise` functions and proceed as in ybeltukov's answer.

```
pwToVec[pw_Piecewise] /; ArrayQ[Append[pw[[1, All, 1]], Last[pw]]] := 
  Piecewise /@ Transpose[Thread /@ Append[First[pw], {Last[pw], True}]];
pwToVec[pw_Piecewise] /; ArrayQ[pw[[1, All, 1]]] := 
  Piecewise[#, Last@pw] & /@ Transpose[Thread /@ First@pw];

Module[{f1 = B, f2 = B^2, f3 = 1 - B^3, plot},
 pw = Piecewise[{{{f1, f2, f3}, B < 1/2}, {{f1, f2, f3}, B > 1/2}}];
 Plot[Evaluate@pwToVec[pw], {B, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One drawback is the use of `Evaluate`, which is necessary to get the different styles.

---

Another way is to post-process the normal plot to add styling to the lines.

```
Module[{f1 = B, f2 = B^2, f3 = 1 - B^3, plot},
 plot = Plot[Piecewise[{{{f1, f2, f3}, B < 1/2}, {{f1, f2, f3}, B > 1/2}}], {B, 0, 1}];
 ListLinePlot[
  Flatten[Transpose@Partition[#, Length[#]/3], 1] &@
   Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity],
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, Options[plot]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A potential drawback is that the code assumes that the `Lines` are generated by `Plot` in a certain order: The lines for the first coordinate are followed by the lines for the second coordinate, which in turn are followed by the lines for the third.  These have the same number of pieces (which is likely to be stable, since a single `Piecewise` is being plotted).

Hint: The `Flatten[Transpose@Partition[...]]` simply reorders the lines, so that as `ListPlot` cycles through the list of `PlotStyles`, the same style gets matched to the lines of each function.

Comment: Interesting solution, +1. Unfortunately `pwToVec` doesn't work with `Piecewise[{{{x^2, 1}, x < 1}, {{2 - x, x}, True}}]`. That's why I suggested a short, but not the general solution :)

Comment: @ybeltukov D'oh!  Thanks.  Fixed now.  I would have posted your way, but you already did it. However, if the piecewise function comes from output (and is really long or I process it repeatedly), then I'd do it my way.

Answer (score 0):

### `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``

You can also use the function `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` to transform your single 3D piecewise function to a list of functions:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{{B, B^3, 1 - B^3}, B < 1/2 || B > 1/2}}];
Plot[Evaluate@Simplify`PWToUnitStep[pw], {B, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Thick]]
```

[image]

If you want to remove the gap use the option `Exclusions -> None` to get

[image]