# Switching between solutions of a fourth order polynomial

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am plotting the roots of a fourth-order polynomial as a function of some parameter $r$ with the following code:

```
mat = {{\[Lambda]^2 - 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 1, 2}, 
       {2, \[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 3}};
sol1 = \[Lambda] /. Solve[Det[mat]== 0, \[Lambda]][[1]];
sol2 = \[Lambda] /. Solve[Det[mat]== 0, \[Lambda]][[2]];
sol3 = \[Lambda] /. Solve[Det[mat]== 0, \[Lambda]][[3]];
sol4 = \[Lambda] /. Solve[Det[mat]== 0, \[Lambda]][[4]];

Plot[{Im[sol1], Im[sol2], Im[sol3], Im[sol4]}, {r, .1, 2}, 
     Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> styles, Exclusions -> None]
Plot[{Re[sol1], Re[sol2], Re[sol3], Re[sol4]}, {r, .1, 2}, 
     Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> styles, Exclusions -> None]
```

The plot of the real part looks fine, but for the imaginary part it looks like Mathematica is switching between a solution and its complex conjugate for different values of the parameter $r$. This is confirmed by plotting the absolute value of the imaginary part of the four different solutions.

Hence, my question is: is there a simple way to make sure that Mathematica is plotting the same solution for every value of $r$, without switching between conjugate solutions?

Comment: Consider using `Root[]`, and put in a conditional as its second argument if you already know where the conjugate switching happens.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by simple, nevertheless I wouldn't say there is a direct approach. Take a look at closely related problems which should clarify a bit more [Finding parameters making real part of eigenvalues vanish](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46417/finding-parameters-making-real-part-of-eigenvalues-vanish/46426#46426), [find where 3 inequalities are simultaneously greater than zero](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/find-where-3-inequalities-are-simultaneously-greater-than-zero/25062#25062)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica's "canonical" orderings of symbolic expressions do not always correspond to numerical orderings<sup>1</sup>, which is (I think) why you're running into problems here.  One way to get around this is to tell Mathematica to calculate the roots numerically instead:

```
mat = {{\[Lambda]^2 - 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 1, 2}, 
       {2, \[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 3}};
sol1 := \[Lambda] /. NSolve[Det[mat] == 0, \[Lambda]][[1]];
sol2 := \[Lambda] /. NSolve[Det[mat] == 0, \[Lambda]][[2]];
sol3 := \[Lambda] /. NSolve[Det[mat] == 0, \[Lambda]][[3]];
sol4 := \[Lambda] /. NSolve[Det[mat] == 0, \[Lambda]][[4]];

Plot[{Im[sol1], Im[sol2], Im[sol3], Im[sol4]}, {r, .1, 2}, 
      Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> styles, Exclusions -> None]
Plot[{Re[sol1], Re[sol2], Re[sol3], Re[sol4]}, {r, .1, 2}, 
      Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> styles, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

[image]

Note the use of `SetDelayed` (aka `:=`) in the definitions of the solutions;  if you use a standard `Set` (`=`), Mathematica will complain that you haven't defined `r` and that it can't solve it numerically.

This does take more time to run than the original code.  You could probably speed things up somewhat by defining something like

```
sols := \[Lambda] /. NSolve[Det[mat] == 0, \[Lambda]]
```

as a list, and then plotting `Im[sols]` and `Re[sols]`.  That way you're only calling `NSolve` once for each value of `r`, rather than four times.

---

<sup>1</sup>  As an example:

```
Sort[{Sqrt[2], 2}]
(* {2, Sqrt[2]} *)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, many thanks! Just one small question: I have never seen these nice colours you have in your plot. They are different than the usual Blue/Red/Orange, right? How did you get them?

Comment: @Funzies They're the [new V10 colors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert very nice and +1 of course...I only posted my answer out of guilt for misreading the r range...:)

Answer (score 1):

**Correction**

I correct my error in relation to range `r`. I post this as a way of visualizing the roots of polynomial (with this correction).

```
mat[\[Lambda]_, 
   r_] := {{\[Lambda]^2 - 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 1, 
    2}, {2, \[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda]/r + 3/(4 r^2) + 3}};
func[\[Lambda]_, r_] := Det[mat[\[Lambda], r]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[With[{res = x /. Solve[func[x, r] == 0, x]},
  max = 1.2 Max[Abs /@ res];
  pts = Through[{Re, Im}[#]] & /@ res;
  Row[{Plot[func[x, r], {x, -max, max}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
     Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.04]], 
     ImageSize -> 200],
    Show[ContourPlot[
      Abs[func[x + I y, r]], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}, 
      Contours -> (# Abs[func[max/2 + max I/2, r]] & /@ {0.1, 0.05, 
          0.01, 0.001}), 
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Pastel"][#^(1/4)] &), Axes -> True,
       AxesStyle -> White], 
     Graphics[{Red, Text[Style["\[Times]", 20, Bold], #] & /@ pts}], 
     ImageSize -> 200]}]], {r, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: in the region r in [0.1,0.2] the solutions are indeed real, however for larger r the solutions become imaginary.

Comment: @Funzies I only based this on your own codes range for r...hence my post...thank you for clarication

Comment: @Funzies mea culpa I mistyped the range! My sincere apologies.

Comment: @Funzies I have corrected my misconception. It may be not what you want but perhaps it may be helpful. Again apologies for my error.