# Is the output to Solve ordered or are the solutions randomly placed?

Tags: equation-solving, order

I am trying to find the roots of a polynomial of eight degree
$$\sin^8\varphi-2\lambda_i^2\sin^6\varphi+(6\lambda_i^2+\lambda_i^4)\sin^4\varphi-(4\lambda_i^2+2\lambda_i^4)\sin^2\varphi+\lambda_i^4=0$$
where $$\lambda _i=\frac{mg-F\frac i n}{2kl}.$$

I have to find the solutions to that eight degree polynomial for each $\lambda_i$ where $i=1...n$, which I did with the following code:

```
F = 1430;(*N*)
k = 1010;(*N/m*)
l = 0.4;(*m*)
m = 10;(*kg*)
g = 9.81;(*m/s^2*)
n = 100;

λ = Table[(m g - F*(i/n))/(2 k l), {i, 0, n, 1}];
resitve = Table[
    Solve[
     x^8 - 2 λ[[i]]^2 x^6 + (6 λ[[i]]^2 + λ[[i]]^4) x^4 - (2 λ[[i]]^4 + 
     4 λ[[i]]^2) x^2 + λ[[i]]^4 == 0, x, Reals
    ], 
   {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}
  ]

kotiMinusBig =   Table[ArcSin[resitve[[i, 1, 1, 2]]]*180/Pi, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
kotiMinusSmall = Table[ArcSin[resitve[[i, 2, 1, 2]]]*180/Pi, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
kotiPlusSmall =  Table[ArcSin[resitve[[i, 3, 1, 2]]]*180/Pi, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
kotiPlusBig =    Table[ArcSin[resitve[[i, 4, 1, 2]]]*180/Pi, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];

tockeMinusBig =   Table[{(F/n)*(i - 1)/1000, kotiMinusBig[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
tockeMinusSmall = Table[{(F/n)*(i - 1)/1000, kotiMinusSmall[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
tockePlusSmall =  Table[{(F/n)*(i - 1)/1000, kotiPlusSmall[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];
tockePlusBig =    Table[{(F/n)*(i - 1)/1000, kotiPlusBig[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[λ], 1}];

ListPlot[{tockeMinusBig, tockeMinusSmall, tockePlusBig, tockePlusSmall}]
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

Now my question is: Does *Mathematica* somehow automatically order the solutions to `Solve`?

Or a question related to the example above: Starting at the left: Does the $y$ value of those green dots really start increasing for $x>0.1$, or do they actually continue to decrease continuously to the blue dots for $x>0.1$, but *Mathematica* ordered them weirdly and now it looks as if the green solutions starts increasing?

Which is the case, and how can I correct it?

NOTE: The problem explicitly says that the $F_i$ domain has to stay discrete.

Comment: It does, see e.g. this answer [Finding parameters making real part of eigenvalues vanish](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46417/finding-parameters-making-real-part-of-eigenvalues-vanish/46426#46426). There are also different posts on this issue, e.g. [Switching between solutions of a fourth order polynomial](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86047/switching-between-solutions-of-a-fourth-order-polynomial?lq=1)

Comment: You cn see them here `resitve = 
  Solve[x^8 - 
     2 l^2 x^6 + (2 l^2 + l^4 + 4 l^2) x^4 - (2 l^4 + 4 l^2) x^2 + 
     l^4 == 0, x, Reals];
Plot[x /. # & /@ resitve, {l, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: @skrat You may have a typo in one of your expressions: the coefficients of the $\sin^2\varphi$ expressions in your formatted equation at the top and in your code do not seem to be the same ($4\lambda_i^2-2\lambda_i^4$ vs. `(2 λ^4 + 4 λ^2)`). Which one is correct?

Comment: @MarcoB: you are right. There was a typo. I have edited my OP now. The code was right. There has to be a "+" sign in the brackets.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: You might have given me the answer, but due to my poor knowledge of mathematica I have no idea what you are trying to show me. :D

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39747/2079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerical roots are sorted in increasing order.

For this problem a cleaner approach is to use `Solve` to get an analytic expression
and plot that:

```
asol = x /. 
   Solve[x^8 - 
      2 \[Lambda]i^2 x^6 + (6 \[Lambda]i^2 + \[Lambda]i^4) x^4 -
     (2 \[Lambda]i^4 + 4 \[Lambda]i^2) x^2 + \[Lambda]i^4 == 0, x];
Show[{Plot[ArcSin[{asol[[1]], asol[[8]]}] /Degree /. 
        \[Lambda]i -> m g/(2 k l) - x,
        {x, 0, F/(2 k l)}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
     Plot[ArcSin[{asol[[2]], asol[[7]]}] /Degree /.
        \[Lambda]i ->  m g/(2 k l) - x, 
        {x, 0, F/(2 k l)}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All], 
     Plot[ArcSin[{asol[[3]], asol[[6]]}]/Degree /. 
        \[Lambda]i ->  m g/(2 k l) - x, 
        {x, 0, F/(2 k l)}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All], 
     Plot[ArcSin[{asol[[4]], asol[[5]] }]/Degree /.
        \[Lambda]i -> m g/(2 k l) - x, 
        {x, 0, F/(2 k l)},PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

Note there are 8 solutions each of which is real on half of the plot and I had to manually sort them so they look continuous.  (This is much easier than sorting your list data however )

Edit: an improved version that splices the pairs of solutions together so it plots smoothly at the transition.

```
 f[x_, soli_, solj_] := Module[{res}, ArcSin[Which[
     Im[res = asol[[soli]] /. \[Lambda]i -> m g/(2 k l) - x] == 0, 
     res ,
     Im[res = asol[[solj]] /. \[Lambda]i -> m g/(2 k l) - x] == 0, 
     res ]]/Degree]
 Plot[{f[x, 1, 8], f[x, 2, 7], f[x, 3, 6], f[x, 4, 5]},
      {x, 0, F/(2 k l)}]
```

Edit: a discrete `ListPlot` version, just showing one curve for clarity.

```
data1 = Flatten[Select[#, Im[#] == 0 &] & /@
    ((ArcSin[{asol[[1]], asol[[8]]}] /Degree
            /. \[Lambda]i -> #) & /@ \[Lambda])];
Length@data1 == Length@\[Lambda]  (* True this will fail if both
        soln's are real or both complex at the same point *)
ListPlot[MapIndexed[{F/n (First@#2 - 1)/1000, #} &, data1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: That is great contribution, george2079. But my problem explicitly orders to avoid the continuous case, meaning the discretization of the $F_i$ can't simply disappear. This wasn't explicitly written in the OP here, because I didn't find it important - I will add it as a note now.

Comment: PS: You probably meant to convert the radians to degrees so I assume `ArcSin[asol[[4]]] Pi/180` (and others...) is a small typo.

Comment: added a discrete plot version.

Comment: I have no ideat what to do to debug this code but this is the error I get: **Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[\[Lambda]]. **

Comment: I am also starting to question if that "continuous" case is really as continuous as you think it is. If you add `PlotRange -> {{.096, .1}, {-2, 2}}` to your `Show[]` you will see what I mean. - the red and the black plots are missing.

Comment: Ok, there is a gap where the curves meet -- Added a fix..