# Plotting the roots of polynomials which coefficients are functions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex, polynomials

I am working on Mathematica just for few days and I am confused to plot the roots of a polynomial which coefficients are functions.

In Mathematica examples, I found some simple examples such as :

```
Plot[Root[#^5 + a # + 1 &, 1], {a, 0, 10}]
```

but when I want to plot real part the equation which I have mentioned below, it doesn't work.

```
DD[z_, y_] := z + y;

EE[z_, y_] := z^2 + y + 1;

H[z_, y_, x_] := x^2 + DD[z, y]*x + EE[z, y];

Plot[Re[Root[H[1, y, x]] &, 1]], {y, 0, 10}]
```

I am so thankful if anyone can help me, I should to fix it today and I am very sad about it.

Comment: Here is an example of plotting roots: [Factoring a two variable polynomial in a special way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/factoring-a-two-variable-polynomial-in-a-special-way/38607#38607)

Comment: Another [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/find-where-3-inequalities-are-simultaneously-greater-than-zero/25062#25062) (more appropriate).

Comment: Hi! You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Dear Artes, thank you so much

Comment: @Dear Michael E2, thank you for your edit, it was the first time that I was writing and thanks for your helpful comment to write in correct style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Plot[Re[Root[H[1, y, #] &, 1]], {y, 0, 10}]
```

or

```
Plot[Re[Root[Function[x, H[1, y, x]], 1]], {y, 0, 10}]
```

to get

[image]

**Note:** The first argument of `Root` should be a pure function.

Comment: @Dear kglr, Thank you so much, the first code was OK, I just replaced x by hashtag