# why is the plot like this?

Tags: plotting, polynomials

Does anybody know the problem?

why is the plot hatched ?  I just want a simple plot.

`g[z_, t_] := 1 + t*z + z^3`

`Plot[Residue[1/(1 + t*z + z^3), {z, Root[Function[z, g[z, t]], 1]}], {t, 0, 10}]`

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code text as you've done in [your first question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216210/1871), rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: @Dear xzczd, my original problem is about polynomials of degree 4 which coefficient are functions of temperature as like as screenshot which have mentioned above. I want to plot T-dependence of roots and residue of them. sorry for posting many screenshots

Comment: I mean, please post the code text instead of the screenshot. Currently we'll have to transcribe the code from your screenshot if we want to test it.

Comment: @xzczd thank you so much, yes, you are right, I should have sent code instead of it's screenshoot

Comment: -1×2, will retract my downvotes as soon as the code text are added to the questions.

Comment: @Dear xzczd, OMG, why so serious? I added the code

Answer (score 1):

`Root` cann't handel the additional parameter `t`!
Try

```
g[z_, t_] := 1 + t z + z^3
root[t_] := Root[Function[z, g[z, t]], 1]  
Plot[Evaluate[Residue[1/g[z, t], {z, root[t]  }]], {t, 0, 10} ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Dear Ulrich Neumann, thank you so much, it was very clear.

Comment: @Arian You're welcome!

Comment: The solution works, but the explanation is incorrect. This is a matter of precision. Try `Plot[Residue[1/g[z, t], {z,  Root[Function[z, g[z, t]], 1]    }], {t, 0, 10},WorkingPrecision->16 ]`.

Comment: @xzcd Thanks for your clarification. Nevertheless in my opinion  a numerical solution which doesn't need high workingprecision is quite reliable.

Comment: That's true, your solution is the better choice for resolving the problem.

Comment: @ xzczd, thanks a lot, the code you have written in comments is so good, and sorry about screenshots, I am just working on mathematica for a few days and I didn't know how to write codes.

Comment: @xzczd, The issue is not inadequate precision, because `WorkingPrecision -> 5` works as well.  This is a bug, in my opinion, and specifying most any `WorkingPrecision` circumvents it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It's still a precision issue :) . This is a bit subtle: we know the default `WorkingPrecision` is `MachinePrecision`, though `N@MachinePrecision == 15.954589770191003`, when used as an **option value**, `WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision` leads to algorithm different from `WorkingPrecision->15.954589770191003`, the former is amount to the traditional float number calculation, the latter calculates in arbitrary precision. This topic is discussed in e.g. the tutorial [`Numbers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#22593). BTW, the underlying model of…

Comment: @bbgodfrey ...arbitrary precisioin calculation of _Mathematica_ is called “significance arithmetic” according to p15 of this doc: https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/compare/HowMapleComparestoMathematica.pdf. But I agree there may be something wrong with the underlying algorithm of `Root`, intuitively `Root[1 + t #1 + #1^3 &, 1]` shouldn't be that hard for machine precision calculation.