# How to plot a Root[] object?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I got a solution in the form of a Root object from an equation:

```
y = Root[-1.1292882469618184`*^35 N^3 + 
    3.327201082265235`*^35 N^2 #1 - 
    3.2676236770106753`*^35 N #1^2 + (1.0697043581639466`*^35 + 
       4.055934940208895`*^29 N^2) #1^3 + 
    8.11186988041779`*^29 N #1^4 + 4.055934940208895`*^29 #1^5 &, 1]
```

which can be evaluated when I substitute the variable N with some number between 1 and 3:

```
y /. N -> 1
0.993688
```

However, I am not able to make Mathematica plot y in the range of [1,3]:

```
Plot[y, {N, 1, 3}]
```

The error message is "Limiting value 1 in {N,1,3} is not a machine-sized real number".

So what is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: As @UlrichNeumann mentions,`N` is a preserved keyword in *Mathematica*, so you'd better not use symbols like `N`, and `C`, `O`, etc., or afterwards things may get weird like this problem. :-)

Comment: This answer your question: [find where 3 inequalities are simultaneously greater than zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/find-where-3-inequalities-are-simultaneously-greater-than-zero)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use  `N` as a symbolname, because it's a predefined Mathematica function!

Try

```
y = Root[-1.1292882469618184`*^35 N^3 + 3.327201082265235`*^35 N^2 #1 -3.2676236770106753`*^35 N #1^2 + (1.0697043581639466`*^35 +4.055934940208895`*^29 N^2) #1^3 + 8.11186988041779`*^29 N #1^4 + 4.055934940208895`*^29 #1^5 &, 1] /. N -> n;
Plot[y ,{n,1,3}]
```

[image]