# Solve doesn't return all solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I got a simple cubic equation as input, but *Mathematica* does not give all solutions, why is this the case here?

```
f[α_] := Sqrt[2] α (Δ + 2g^2/Ω(α Conjugate[α]))

Solve[f[α] == 0, α]
```

> ```
> {{α -> 0}}
> ```

There should also be the solution where $\alpha \in$ Real, so that $|\alpha|^2 = -\frac{\Delta\Omega}{2g^2}$ under the condition $\Delta\Omega < 0$.

Comment: Please include your code in `InputForm`, not $\LaTeX$.

Comment: If you replace `(\[Alpha] Conjugate[\[Alpha]])` with `Abs[\[Alpha]]^2` then `Solve` will do better. It really does not know how to work with `Conjugate` (it's hardly cognisant of `Abs`, but in this case "hardly" > "not at all").

Comment: So what is your problem? Since it does not return all solutions, have you tried various options (utilities) of `Solve`? This review should clarify the issue: [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve). But at first you should try `Solve[ f[α] == 0, α, Reals]`, it yields your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instruct Mathematica (as well as us) what the variables, such as delta, g and omega, are assumed to be: imaginary or real, and if real, positive or negative or both?  I will assume in the following that they are real, positive.

```
\[Alpha] = a + I*b;
```

then the expression for the left-hand parts of equations:

```
 exprRe = Simplify[
  Re[Sqrt[2] \[Alpha] (\[CapitalDelta] + 
      2 g^2/\[CapitalOmega] (\[Alpha] Conjugate[\[Alpha]]))], \
{Element[a, Reals], 
   Element[b, Reals], \[CapitalDelta] > 0, \[CapitalOmega] > 0, g > 0}]


exprIm = Simplify[
  Im[Sqrt[2] \[Alpha] (\[CapitalDelta] + 
      2 g^2/\[CapitalOmega] (\[Alpha] Conjugate[\[Alpha]]))], \
{Element[a, Reals], 
   Element[b, Reals], \[CapitalDelta] > 0, \[CapitalOmega] > 0, 
   g > 0}]`
```

The outcome is:

```
(*    (Sqrt[2] a (2 a^2 g^2 + 
   2 b^2 g^2 + \[CapitalDelta] \[CapitalOmega]))/\[CapitalOmega]  *)

(* (Sqrt[2] b (2 a^2 g^2 + 
   2 b^2 g^2 + \[CapitalDelta] \[CapitalOmega]))/\[CapitalOmega]  *)
```

Let us now solve them:

```
Solve[{exprRe == 0, exprIm == 0}, {a, b}]
```

Here is the result:

```
{{b -> -(Sqrt[-2 a^2 g^2 - \[CapitalDelta] \[CapitalOmega]]/(
    Sqrt[2] g))}, {b -> 
   Sqrt[-2 a^2 g^2 - \[CapitalDelta] \[CapitalOmega]]/(
   Sqrt[2] g)}, {a -> 0, b -> 0}}
```