# Mathematica returns different results when requested by Reduce, Solve

Tags: equation-solving

When I request with Reduce, Mathematica returns:

```
In[13]:= N[Reduce[X^3-26X+1 == 0,X, Reals]]                                     
Out[13]= X == -5.11814 || X == 0.0384637 || X == 5.07968
```

However, when I request with Solve, it returns three complex roots

```
In[15]:= N[Solve[X^3-26X+1 == 0,X]]                                             
                                                            -16
Out[15]= {{X -> 5.07968 + 0. I}, {X -> 0.0384637 + 4.44089 10    I}, 
                            -16
{X -> -5.11814 - 4.44089 10    I}}
```

I think the different here is the Reals field. However, I'm confused about the correctness of result. Which one should I follow when I want to solve the equations.

Thanks

Comment: Use `Chop` on the results form `Solve`.

Comment: @Kuba: it doesn't make any difference

Comment: `X /. N[Solve[X^3 - 26 X + 1 == 0, X]] // Chop` -> `{5.07968, 0.0384637, -5.11814}` which is the same result as from `Reduce`.

Comment: Also, to give you refference to the answer, please take a look at [difference between Solve and Reduce](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17127/5478)

Comment: So I think I'd better use reduce right?

Comment: You'd better use what fits your needs :) In this particular case you can see that the result is the same. In other it can be different as described in the link I've provided. If one was absolutelly better than another what would be the purpose of the other existance? :)

Comment: @Loi.Luu If you want the same result use e.g. `Solve[X^3 - 26 X + 1 == 0, X, Cubics -> False]`. This answer includes explanation: [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).