# Minimizing a potential using Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am having problems minimizing a potential:

$\text{V}(h,\eta)=\gamma  \left(-h^2\right) \left(\eta ^2 \cos ^2(\theta )+\eta  \cos (\delta ) \sqrt{-\eta ^2-h^2+1} \sin (2 \theta )+\left(-\eta ^2-h^2+1\right) \sin ^2(\theta )\right)$ (Input code below)

```
V = -h^2 γ (η^2 Cos[θ]^2 + (1 - h^2 - η^2) Sin[θ]^2 + η Sqrt[1 - h^2 - η^2] Cos[δ] Sin[2 θ])
```

I try to minimize simply using:

```
sol = Solve[{D[V, h] == 0, D[V, η] == 0}, {h, η}]
```

It seems to solve quickly and with no problems giving me 9 solutions, these solutions depend on the parameters $\theta, \delta, \gamma$.

However if for example I try to calculate:

```
Chop[N[D[V,h] /. sol /. θ -> 1 /. δ -> 1 /. γ -> 1]]
```

The output it gives is:

> ```
> {0, -0.104069, 0, 0, -0.484451, 0.104069, 0, 0, 0.484451}
> ```

As you can see extrema `2`, `5`, `6` and `9` are not even close to zero! It seems *Mathematica* is solving this incorrectly, or maybe the solutions are only valid in specific regions (not the full domain)?

Does anyone have any ideas? I thought maybe the problem was with the square root in the function (otherwise it's a simple polynomial) but have tried solving it using the Lagrange multiplier method taking a function $V(h,η,s)$ and $s=\sqrt{1-h^2-η^2}$ but it also doesn't seem to give me all zero solutions when I sub it in to the Lagrange equation $\frac{\partial V}{\partial h}+\lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial g}$, where $g=s-\sqrt{1-h^2-η^2}=0$, the constraint applied to this function.

Any ideas what's happening ? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Hello ! It increases the quality of your question when you format appropriately your code and provide it in `InputForm` rather than $\LaTeX$. See the help centre for guidelines on how to properly format your code :)

Comment: The only part where I have put code is in the input, although its in latex form its pretty self explantory, only 1 line and its simply checking the value of the derivative of V w.r.t h at the extrema calculated by solsimp, for some random values of θ,δ,γ,Δ,ϵ. I have changed it to input text for your liking though. Do you have any ideas about my problem Nikola?

Comment: You should provide `Vsimp` in *Mathematica* `InputForm` so it can be easily copied.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Why not change your username into something a little more memorable? As far as your problem is concerned, I'd try and write the $ \sin(2\theta) = 2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) $ and then complete the square. Then you will have a square plus "something" which will be easier to feed to `Reduce`. `Solve` uses generic parameters whereas `Reduce` finds you their domains as well (see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) for instance). I assume you are wanting a solution in the complex domain?

Comment: The presence of both a radical containing variables of interest, and parameters, means there will be solutions that, for some parameter values, are parasites (they satisfy a de-radicalized variant of the system but not the system itself). It is these that, for specific param values, fail to give zero on substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are minimum example of your problem

```
f = Sqrt[a^2 - x^2] + x;
Plot[{f /. a -> 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

It obviously has only one extremum, but `Solve` returns two

```
sol = Solve[D[f, x] == 0, {x}]
D[f, x] /. sol /. a -> 1
```

> ```
> {{x -> -(a/Sqrt[2])}, {x -> a/Sqrt[2]}}
> {2, 0}
> ```

It is because `Sqrt` is a multivalued function in the complex domain. Let's plot both Riemann surface sheets of `Sqrt`

```
f2 = -Sqrt[a^2 - x^2] + x;
Plot[{f /. a -> 1, f2 /. a -> 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Now it is clear that the parasitic solution came from the `-Sqrt`.

If you solve over `Reals` domain the result is correct

```
sol = Solve[D[f, x] == 0, {x}, Reals]
D[f, x] /. sol /. a -> 1
```

> ```
> {{x -> Sqrt[a^2]/Sqrt[2]}}
> {0}
> ```

The original problem is too complicated to solve it over the real domain. But you can always select right solutions manually.

Another possibility is setting parameters θ,δ,γ before `Solve`

```
θ = 1;
δ = 1;
γ = 1;
sol = Solve[D[V, h] == 0 && D[V, \[Eta]] == 0, {h, \[Eta]}];
Chop[N[D[V, h] /. sol]]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you are saying but I do not understand why this is the case. I think I am simply being very thick here but why is there this degeneracy in the solutions when you do not solve over the reals? Why is there no reflection when I swap $\delta$ from 1 to -1? Is it because it isn't squared in the potential? I don't understand why this is happening (but what you have shown seems to be the cause of my problem). Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I think it is because root is multivalued function in the complex domain.

Comment: I see...I think. However,I can't really pick the right solution by hand because this function is in an automated process which uses it and its extrema to calculate relevant phenomenology. I need to somehow automatically pick up the correct solution. What I am actually looking for is the global minima of a function (a more complicated version of the function I showed here) for a scan of the parameters theta, delta and some other parameters. So if I find the global minima but `D[V,h]` at this minima is non zero, this probably means that the global minima is at minus theta?

Comment: No...it doesn't matter if `D[V,h]` is non zero this should still be a correct extrema of the function, as the function is degenerate in a reflection in theta. So there should be no problem I think? It's simply a problem in mathematica that it isn't able to solve it simply.

Comment: If you change sign of root in `V` than solutions swap. The problem is how to chose the correct sheet of the Riemann surface.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by choosing the correct sheet, but if the solutions swap in a reflection of theta, this means that the extrema from Solve are correct and it is a limitation of mathematica that it does not correctly work when you substitute it back in. Correct?

Comment: In my last comment by "root" I meant `Sqrt`. Some solutions are correct for `+Sqrt` others for `-Sqrt`. It is too difficult for *Mathematica* to choose in which case what solution is valid for any θ,δ,γ. You can always set them before `Solve` and get only valid solutions!

Comment: Okay, sorry to keep bothering you but just to make sure I understand you: If I look at my solution to the minimization and it ends up being say, `{-1.10398, 0, 1.10398, -0.0453391, 0, 0.0453391, 0}`, this means that for this branch of `Sqrt`, solutions 1,3,4,6 are not valid, but would be valid for `-Sqrt`. So I *cannot* use these solutions as I am only interested in `+Sqrt` as my potential has a `+Sqrt`. The solutions where `D[V,h]=/=0` are 'unphysical' in a sense and I should discard them?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Cheers! Very helpful!