# Solving an algebraic equation with one or more constraints?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Just as a simple example, say I wanted to solve Sin[x] == a for x with the constraints -1<=a<=1 and 0 < x < Pi. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Solve[Sin[x] == a && -1 <= a <= 1 && 0 < x < Pi, x]`

Comment: You should browse another questions on equation-solving. `Solve` here is just an adequate approach, but in more general cases one would rather use `Reduce` or `Solve[..., MaxExtraConditions-> All]`. Take a look at [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129) or [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)