# Is everything in Mathematica ultimately stored as a rule?

Tags: functions, replacement, core-language

My current understanding about Mathematica is that everything, at the lowest level, ends up as replacement rules.
First question: is this true?
Second question: does Mathematica "gloss over" these rules by representing them as functions?   [image]   doesn't seem to be expressed as a rule.

Third question: does the by value/by reference question have any when you "pass" a value to a Mathematica function?

Comment: Well, obviously a system based on rules *only*, would only be able to do endless expression rewritings, but not much more. Even if one can build such a model of computation consistently, this is not what we see in Mathematica. From the user's viewpoint, (many) built-in functions are terminals, because their actions are no longer governed by rules. For example, when Mathematica sees `Sin[0.15]`, it calls the built-in numerical implementation of `Sin` to make a computation - at which point it arguably leaves the rule-based paradigm. And similarly for most other useful lower-level actions.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin-I guess this should have been obvious. Rules are enough for doing algebra, but not for calculating a sine  or loading a file. Is my simple function transformed into a rule?

Comment: I was tempted to edit your title: _"Do rules rule?"_ But my nose is still bleeding as a result of a limerick.

Comment: @belisarius-I like your title more than mine.

Comment: Have a look at `DownValues[f]` that's where the rules are hiding in this case

Comment: Rules are not capable to express many underlying results produced by `Mathematica`. For example consider what `Reduce` can do better than `Solve`, for more details read this post: [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: David Wagners book, which is available as a free download here, has a good description of this.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Your simple function *is* a rule. The only top-level (user-defined) functions in Mathematica which are not rules, AFAIK, are pure functions (defined using `Function`).

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe But generally, rules seem to be the core paradigm of the Mathematica language - more fundamental than functional or structural or procedural ones. Roman Maeder directly admits this in his "Programming in Mathematica".

Comment: @belisarius You made my profile quotes. Again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard At your service :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define a function `f`, you are (a) applying `Set` or `SetDelayed` to a pattern, (b) creating a rule, (c) associating the rule with a symbol (`f`), and (d) storing that in `DownValues` (usually).

```
FullForm[Hold[f[x_] := x^2]]
(* Hold[SetDelayed[f[Pattern[x, Blank[]]], Power[x, 2]]] *)

f[x_] := x^2
DownValues@f
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2} *)
```

#### First question: is it true that "everything in Mathematica is ultimately stored as a rule?"

No: for example `2` is not a rule.  It's just 2.  So not everything is a rule, just functions.  Everything is an expression, ... some expressions (as a side-effect) create and store rules in DownValues.

#### Second question: does Mathematica "gloss over" these rules by representing them as functions?

Yes and no.  They give you a glossy shortcut for input:

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

instead of requiring you to write something like

```
AppendTo[DownValues[f], HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2]
```

There was one misunderstanding in your question; you asked about the output of

```
FullForm[f[x]]
```

This is **not** showing you the definition of the function `f`.  It is showing you the result of applying `f` to `x`.  See the following:

```
FullForm[f[2]]
(* 4 *)
```

If you want to see the definition of `f` you should either use `Information` (which is glossy and not very useful) or `DownValues` which contains what you're after.

#### Third question: does the by value/by reference question have any when you "pass" a value to a Mathematica function?

Work on the assumption that Mathematica is pretty smart "under the hood" about pass by value/ pass by reference.

Comment: Also comments (* ... *) and Mathematica packages are not stored as rules. They are not even expressions.