# Simple Solve example fails: why?

Tags: equation-solving

`Solve` is an amazing tool, but sometimes it doesn't work in the way I expect it to. The particular instance that is confusing me right now is this:

```
Solve[a==b&&c==d,a]
```

I expect it to tell me that `a->b`, but instead it gives no solutions. I am using version 9, if this makes a difference.

To be clear, my question is *not* how do I fix this example (e.g. "Ian, just do `Solve[a==b&&c==d,{a,c}]`"), but rather, *why* does it think there are no solutions. Bonus if you can provide a tool that does think `a->b` is a solution.

**Update:**

Thanks to @MichaelE2 in the comments for the illustrative example -- it made obvious what was not obvious to me before; `Solve` performs a task which is only an approximation to the everyday meaning of the word "solve". When I think of the expression `Solve[expr,vars]`, what I want it to do is treat every symbol not in the list `vars` as "known" and solve for the "unknown" symbols in `vars`. What it actually does is try to find a set of replacements for the symbols in `vars` such that `expr/.soln` is `True`.

This slight difference in meaning is usually not an issue, but for examples like the one above, and also ones like

```
Solve[{a==b,b==c},c]
```

these two meanings give very different, but respectively correct, answers.

I guess the updated question is just the bonus: is there a function which does a better job of approximating the "usual" definition of solve.

Comment: It seems that the number of variables has to equal the number of equations, although I couldn't find this in the documentation for `Solve`.  Try `Solve[a==b&&c==d,{a, c}]`

Comment: Compare with `Solve[a == b || c == d, a]`, and note that `c == d` does not evaluate to `True`, unless `c` and `d` have values.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see, so an explanation for `Solve` better than the documentation`s "`Solve[expr,vars]` attempts to solve the system `expr` of equations or inequalities for the variables `vars`." would be "`Solve[expr,vars]` attempts to find replacement rules for the symbol(s in) `vars` which cause the statement `expr` to be `True`".

Comment: You don't have to specify all the variables. `Solve` provides generic solutions, to get the full solution set you should add this option `MaxExtraConditions -> All` or sometimes you'd better use `Reduce`. See [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).