# Solution given by Wolfram Alpha but not _Mathematica_

Tags: equation-solving

Why will *Mathematica* not give a soluion to `Solve[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, x]], j]`, but Wolfram Alpha will?

Comment: `Reduce` works.

Comment: The WolframAlpha result can be produced with `Reduce[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, x]], j, Reals]`.  In general, you should *not* assume that Mathematica commands typed into WolframAlpha will be executed verbatim on the server side.

Comment: I see - I didn't realise this!

Comment: @martin Then you might be interested in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve).  The answers might lead you to try `Solve[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, x]], j, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`, an option which I had forgotten.

Comment: Michael E2, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram|Alpha points out that this is a solution over the reals:

[image]

This is how to get this solution in Mathematica:

```
Reduce[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, x]], j, Reals]

(* Log[x] != 0 && j == x^E^-ProductLog[Log[x]^2] *)
```

Wolfram|Alpha tries to interpret input as natural language.  Certain Mathematica expressions work, but they don't always do the same thing as in Mathematica.  Here W|A interprets the input as "solve this equation with reasonable assumptions", not as "run the Mathematica code `Solve[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, x]], j]`".

Comment: Great - that you :) - Had me a little confused!

Comment: Is it better to use `Reduce` in most cases?

Comment: ... Is there any way of solving for an extra `Log`? ie `Reduce[Log[x] == Log[j, Log[j, Log[j, x]]], j, Reals]`?

Comment: @martin `Solve` tends to be faster because it doesn't seek a general solution.  E.g. in v8 `Solve[Sin[x] == y, x]` returned `{{x -> ArcSin[y]}}` which is not the general solution.  `Reduce[Sin[x] == y, x]` returned `C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (x == \[Pi] - ArcSin[y] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] || 
   x == ArcSin[y] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])` which is general.  I couldn't find a v9 example off the top of my head but that's the main difference. In v9 (?) `Solve` can take the option `Method -> Reduce` to do what `Reduce` does ... (check the docs for another example on this).

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks - that helps me to understand a little better.