# Mathematica unable to solve equation numerically while Wolfram|Alpha can

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, wolfram-alpha-queries

I want to solve the following equation

```
2 x == Sinh[x]
```

*Mathematica* is unable to do so

```
In[1]:= Solve[2 x == Sinh[x], x]
During evaluation of In[20]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>
Out[1]= Solve[2 x == Sinh[x], x]
```

However, Wolfram|Alpha can successfully solve the equation

[image: Wolfram|Alpha query]

How can I achieve the same in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try `Solve[2 x == Sinh[x], x, Reals]`.  This is a common question - here's a [similar example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/).

Comment: You didn't ask _Mathematica_ for a numerical solution, you asked for a symbolic one.

Comment: If I ask Mathematica for a numerical solution, using NSolve, it gives me the same error, though.

Comment: @Sven86, Use `NSolve[2 x == Sinh[x], x, Reals]`. `NSolve` has a default domain of `Complexes` just like `Solve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[2 x - Sinh[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[2 x == Sinh[x], {x, #}] & /@ {-2, 0, 2}

{{x -> -2.17732}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 2.17732}}
```

Comment: @Sven86 This syntax also works, though I believe it is undocumented: `FindRoot[2 x == Sinh[x], {x, {-2, 0, 2}}]`.  Note that the output form is different:  `{x -> {-2.17732, 0., 2.17732}}`.