# Rearranging 5 equations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to rearrange 5 equations in terms of 5 variables.  I have the equations for `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` and `y5` in terms of `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` and `x5`, but I want to solve for `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` and `x5` in terms of `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` and `y5`.  I tried the following:

```
Solve[{y1 == x4*((x2*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
       y2 == x4*((x1*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
       y3 == x4*((x1*x2 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
       y4 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x2 + x3)),
       y5 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x1 + x3))}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

and the output

> ```
> {}
> ```

I looked at this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) and thought that maybe I should be using `Reduce`, so I tried the following:

```
Reduce[{y1 == x4*((x2*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y2 == x4*((x1*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y3 == x4*((x1*x2 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y4 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x2 + x3)), 
        y5 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x1 + x3))}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

as well as this:

```
Reduce[{y1 == x4*((x2*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y2 == x4*((x1*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y3 == x4*((x1*x2 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
        y4 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x2 + x3)),
        y5 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x1 + x3)), 
        y1 > 0, y2 > 0, y3 > 0, y4 > 0, y5 > 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

and *Mathematica* just gets stuck calculating for a long time and doesn't display anything.  Is this the correct way to solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: `x4` is just a scale factor for the `y`s

Comment: You get an empty solution set because there are no solutions. As it happens, anything that might make the equations vanish also makes denominators zero. So you are getting an appropriate result.

Comment: So the problem is that I didn't specify that the denominators can't be zero?  Is there a way to specify this is not the case? I tried: "Solve[{y1 == 
   x4*((x2*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)), 
  y2 == x4*((x1*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 
        2*x5^3)), 
  y3 == x4*((x1*x2 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 
        2*x5^3)), y4 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x2 + x3)),
  y5 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x1 + x3)), (x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 
     2*x5^3) != 0, (2*x5 + x2 + x3) != 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]"  but that didn't work.

Comment: Hi belisarius, I'm aware that y scales with x4, but I'm not sure where you're going with your statement.  Could you explain?

Comment: Actually `Solve` will automatically enforce that denominators do not vanish. In effect it does what you did explicitly. And it turns out that no solutions exist.

Comment: What do you mean by no solutions exist? I have 5 independent variables and I just want to rearrange the equations in terms of the other 5 variables, which I thought would be possible with 5 independent equations.

Comment: @belisarius Oops.  I'm new and didn't realize I'm supposed to use the @ symbol to direct my comments.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielLichtblau noted in the comments, `Solve` correctly returns an empty set because there are no solutions to the system. But if you want to rearrange the equations of the system in terms of `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4`, and `x5`, you can do something like the following:

```
Module[{res,
    vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5},
    eqn1 = y1 == x4*((x2*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)),
    eqn2 = y2 == x4*((x1*x3 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)),
    eqn3 = y3 == x4*((x1*x2 - x5^2)/(x1*x2*x3 - (x5^2)*(x1 + x2 + x3) - 2*x5^3)),
    eqn4 = y4 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x2 + x3)),
    eqn5 = y5 == x4*(1/(2*x5 + x1 + x3))},
  res = Table[Simplify@Flatten@Solve[j, {i}], {i, vars}, {j, {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5}}];
  res = vars /. Flatten@res[[All, -2 ;; -1]];
  Table[(Thread[vars == #] & /@ res)[[i, i]], {i, Length[res]}]]

(*{{x1 == -x3 - 2 x5 + x4/y5},
   {x2 == -x3 - 2 x5 + x4/y4},
   {x3 == -x2 - 2 x5 + x4/y4},
   {x4 == (x2 + x3 + 2 x5) y4},
   {x5 == (x4 - (x2 + x3) y4)/(2 y4)}}*)
```