# How can I get all solutions of a system of equations with Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving

The post [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) discusses the difference between `Reduce` and `Solve`. Now, with the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}
a^2 + 6b - 7=0,\\
a - \dfrac{1}{b}=0.
\end{cases}$$

where $a$, $b$ are real numbers. I tried

```
Solve[{a^2 + 6 b - 7 == 0 && a - 1/b == 0}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{a -> -3, b -> -(1/3)}, {a -> 1, b -> 1}, {a -> 2, b -> 1/2}}
> ```

But when I tried

```
Reduce[{a^2 + 6 b - 7 == 0 && a - 1/b == 0}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

I could not get all the solutions. I only got

> ```
> (a == -3 || a == 1 || a == 2) && b == 1/6 (7 - a^2)
> ```

How can I get all the solutions with `Reduce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output is as shown you can use [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html):

```
Reduce[{a^2 + 6 b - 7 == 0 && a - 1/b == 0}, {a, b}, Reals];

{ToRules[%]}
```

> ```
> {{a -> -3, b -> 1/6 (7 - a^2)},
>  {a -> 1, b -> 1/6 (7 - a^2)},
>  {a -> 2, b -> 1/6 (7 - a^2)}}
> ```

If you are attempting to find many solutions you may need to increase the System Option [`"DiscreteSolutionBound"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html):

```
SetSystemOptions[{"ReduceOptions" -> "DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 100}]
```

> *Mathematica* enumerates the solutions explicitly only if the number of integer solutions of the system does not exceed the maximum of the
>   p^th power of the value of the system option DiscreteSolutionBound,
>   where p is the dimension of the solution lattice of the equations, and
>   the second element of the value of the system option
>   ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014), just use `Backsubstitution -> True` while using `Reduce`,

```
Solve[{a^2 + 6 b - 7 == 0 && a - 1/b == 0}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

$\left\{\left\{a\to -3,b\to -\frac{1}{3}\right\},\{a\to 1,b\to 1\},\left\{a\to 2,b\to \frac{1}{2}\right\}\right\}$

```
Reduce[{a^2 + 6 b - 7 == 0 && a - 1/b == 0}, {a, b}, 
Backsubstitution -> True]
```

$\left(a=-3\land b=-\frac{1}{3}\right)\lor (a=1\land b=1)\lor \left(a=2\land b=\frac{1}{2}\right)$

You can finde the Options Reduce and Solve with:

```
Options /@ {Reduce, Solve} // Column
```

> {Backsubstitution -> False, Cubics -> False, GeneratedParameters -> C,
>   Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> False, WorkingPrecision -> ∞}
>
> {Cubics -> True, GeneratedParameters -> C,   InverseFunctions ->
>   Automatic, MaxExtraConditions -> 0,   Method -> Automatic, Modulus ->
>   0, Quartics -> True,   VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision
>   -> ∞}

Comment: you mean `Options /@ {Reduce, Resolve} // Column`??