# Don't understand results from solving polynomial equation

Tags: equation-solving, inverse

I attempting to solve an equation for x so that I may then switch x & y to get the inverse function. This is the code I have for solving for x:

```
f[x_] := -3 + (x^3)/1367 + (x^5)/2734        
mySolution = Solve[f[x] == y, x]
```

When I execute this code, *Mathematica* outputs:

> ```
> {{x -> Root[-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 2]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 3]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 4]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 5]}}
> ```

Could someone help me understand why this is the output when solving the function for x? I don't see how I could switch x & y with the output *Mathematica* has given me.

Comment: What do you expect? There will be multiple values for *x* in *f* that have the same result, and these are the roots indicated.

Comment: I don't understand why there are '#' and '&' in the result.

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to solving fifth order polynomial and in general it is impossible to solve such equations in terms of radicals.  For  more on these toppics read e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768) and [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129). There are many more related posts, nonetheless your question is a duplicate of the first link.

Comment: By the way  objects like `-8202 - 2734 y + 2 #1^3 + #1^5 &` represents so called pure functions and you can find posts discussing related aspects.

Comment: @artes With the comment below the answer in your link it looks like there's a problem in v10. Did you check that?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries   What kind of problems have you found?  E.g. `Solve[(3 - Cos[4x])(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, InverseFunctions -> True]` yields slightly different form of solutions then in previous versions, nevertheless both are equivalent.

Comment: @artes I haven't done anything here. I was referring to [a comment below the answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#comment243445_13768) of yours you linked to. That seems to suggest a problem in v10 and it looked like you hadn't seen the comment.