# Non-algebraic equation in the set of complex numbers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

The following equation in $\mathbb{C}$:

$4z^2+8|z|^2-3=0$

is not algebraic and has 4 solutions : $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and $\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
The Solve function in Mathematica only returns the 2 real values :

```
Solve[4 z^2 + 8 Abs[z]^2 - 3 == 0, Complexes]

(* {{z -> -(1/2)}, {z -> 1/2}} *)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: This discussion on [Reduce vs Solve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) may be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Reduce did it :

```
Reduce[4 z^2 + 8 Abs[z]^2 - 3 == 0,z, Complexes]
```

> z == -(1/2) || z == 1/2 || z == -((I Sqrt[3])/2) || z == (I Sqrt[3])/2

Or using the option Method-> Reduce in Solve :

```
Solve[ 4 z^2 + 8 Abs[z]^2 - 3 == 0, z, Complexes, Method -> Reduce]
```

> {{z -> -(1/2)}, {z -> 1/2}, {z -> -((I Sqrt[3])/2)}, {z -> ( I Sqrt[3])/2}}

Or using an option introduced in version 8 :

```
Solve[ 4 z^2 + 8 Abs[z]^2 - 3 == 0, z, Complexes, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> {{z -> -(1/2)}, {z -> 1/2}, {z -> -((I Sqrt[3])/2)}, {z -> ( I Sqrt[3])/2}}

This way one gets replacement rules in the usual Solve way instead of a boolean expression, in case the former is more useful.

I discovered that the variable name can be omitted both in Solve and Reduce. But it cannot be considered good practice. The mention of the domain (complexes) is also superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

```
Solve[4 z^2 + 8 Abs[z]^2 - 3 == 0 && z \[Element] Complexes, z]
```

> {{z -> -(1/2)}, {z -> 1/2}, {z -> -((I Sqrt[3])/2)}, {z -> (
>      I Sqrt[3])/2}}

Comment: Why isn't this equivalent to the code in the question? I can't find anything in the documentation to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A pedestrian approach, overkill in this case, is to separate into explicit real and imaginary parts both for the expression(s) and variable(s).

```
expr = 4 z^2 + 8  Abs[z]^2 - 3;
{re, im} = 
 ComplexExpand[{Re[expr], Im[expr]}, z] /. {Re[z] -> rez, Im[z] -> imz}
solns = Solve[{re, im} == 0];
rez + I*imz /. solns

(* Out[380]= {-3 + 4 imz^2 + 12 rez^2, 8 imz rez}

Out[382]= {-(1/2), 1/2, -((I Sqrt[3])/2), (I Sqrt[3])/2} *)
```

Comment: Overkill, indeed in this simple case.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `Complexes` for `Solve`or `Reduce` suffices as does just doing it yourself (as alluded to by Daniel:Lichtblau):

```
x + I y /.Solve[{4 (x^2 - y^2) + 8 (x^2 + y^2) - 3 == 0, 8 x y == 0}, {x, y}]
```

yield:

```
 {-((I Sqrt[3])/2), (I Sqrt[3])/2, -(1/2), 1/2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Solve[4 z^2 + 8 z Conjugate[z] - 3 == 0, z]
(* {z -> -1/2}, {z -> 1/2}, {z -> (-I/2)*Sqrt[3]}, {z -> (I/2)*Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

Comment: Yes, that works also. It's even simpler than adding options to Solve in this case. Thanks.