# Solve doesn't give me all the solutions I expect

Tags: equation-solving

I have a problem with *Mathematica* 10, and I really don't know what's happening here. I try to plot some orbitals and then solve a simple equation. But *Nathematica* only gives me one the solution, `phi -> -Pi/2`, instead of two which I think should be there. Also it doesn't tell me, what theta should be.

When a friend of mine, who still uses *Mathematica* 9 runs the exact same code, he gets the right result. Why?

```
Clear[Y11, Y112, ph, th];
Y11 = SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, th, ph];
Y112 = SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, th, ph];
Fx = 1/Sqrt[2]*(Y11 - Y112);
Fy = 1/Sqrt[2]*(Y11 + Y112);
Solve[Abs[Fx]^2 == 0]
```

I also tried to use reduce command or to write

```
Solve[Abs[Fx]^2 == 0, {ph, th}]
```

but this doesn't work as well.

P.S.: The first picture shows my friend's code and the second one mine.

[image: my friends code]
[image: my code]

Comment: It is not surprising at all, I am not sure you can get more solutions with `Reduce`, but certain clever approach could. You should remember limitations of `Solve`, e.g. I recommend to read e.g.  [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).

Comment: Edit your question and Copy and Paste the code into the question so that others can run it and offer you help.  Format the code when you paste it with the code button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking `Abs` and squaring a quantity equal to `0` adds nothing and apparently confuses `Reduce`.  Try

```
Reduce[Fx == 0, {ph, th}] // Simplify
(* C[1] ∈ Integers && (th == 2 π C[1] || π + 2 π C[1] == th || ph == π (1/2 + C[1]))*)
```