# How do I find solutions to a polynomial equation which do not depend on the values of the unknowns?

Tags: equation-solving

If I type

```
Solve[a t == 1, {a}, Complexes]
```

I get the solution

```
{{a -> 1/t}}
```

This is because Mathematica is treating the variable $t$ as a complex number.  What I am looking for is a convenient way to look for solutions $a$ that work for all $t$, i.e. I want to treat $t$ as a degree one polynomial $p(t)=t$.  In this case, there are no complex number solutions $a$ to the equation $a t = 1$.

Alternatively, is there anyway to look for solutions to an equation which depend only polynomially on the unknown variables (for example, $a=t$ would be an acceptable solution, but not $a=\frac{1}{t}$)?

Comment: Just assume `t` to be a given polynomial of order `n` in `a` by completing the system of equations and then there will be `n+1` complex solutions to the equations. Otherwise the system will not try to guess what you might want. Nontheless there are some options in `Solve` like `MaxExtraConditions`, `Method->Reduce` etc..  Take a look e.g. at [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: Perhaps `SolveAlways[a t == 1, t]` or `SolveAlways[a + b t ==t, t]`?

Comment: Maybe `In[831]:= Reduce[a t == 1, {a}, Complexes]

Out[831]= t != 0 && a == 1/t` ??

Answer (score 2):

I've used `CoefficientArrays` for stuff like this.

I.e.  `CoefficientArrays[expression, t]` will give a list of sparse-arrays of coefficients of $t^n$ in `expression`, where $n$ ranges from $0$ to the highest power of $t$ present.

So `Flatten[Normal/@CoefficientArrays[a t == 1,t]]` yields:

`{-1, a}`

All of which you want to be zero.  So you can apply `#==0&/@` the output and have all the equations you want available to pipe into `Reduce` or the favorite solver of your choice.

All the zeros in sparse matrices from complete set of possible monomials can be a little overwhelming especially at higher orders, so I tend to use `ArrayRules` as follows:

```
    treatAsBasisPolys[expr_, vars_] := Map[Last[#] == 0 &, 
       Flatten[(ArrayRules /@ CoefficientArrays[expr, Flatten[{vars}]]) /. 
                ArrayRules[a_] :> {} -> a  
          (* This last rule is a cheap hack to deal with the fact:
             first element returned by CoefficientArrays is a scalar *)
       ]
      ]
```

Examples:

- `treatAsBasisPolys[a T == 1, T] // Reduce` $\mapsto$

`False`

- `treatAsBasisPolys[a T == b, T] // Reduce` $\mapsto$

`b == 0 && a == 0`

- `treatAsBasisPolys[a U + b V == c, {U, V}] // Reduce` $\mapsto$

`b == 0 && c == 0 && a == 0`

- `treatAsBasisPolys[a u + b v  + c u v == 15 u v, {u, v}] // Reduce` 
  $\mapsto$

`b == 0 && c == 15 && a == 0`

- `treatAsBasisPolys[a U + b V  + c U V + d + q U^18 ==  (13 + g U) (-3 + k V),
  {U, V}] // Reduce` $\mapsto$

`d == -39 && q == 0 && c == g k && b == 13 k && a == -3 g`