# Reduce a system of nonlinear equations (CES utility maximization in economics)

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I need to reduce a simple system of 3 equations in 3 variables. Reduce can't handle it directly, but works if I combine the first two equations.

[image: FullSystem]

Here is the code:

```
Reduce[{z == x^a, z == y^a, x + y == b, a > 0, b > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, 
    {x, y, z} , Reals, Backsubstitution ->True]

Reduce[{x^a == y^a, x + y == b, a > 0, b > 0, x > 0, y > 0}, 
{x,y} , Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

It's even easy to solve by hand! I spent days adding assumptions without success.

I need to reduce the full 3 equation system for the toolkit I'm creating. Is there a way to reduce the full system by adding options or assumptions?

I'm writing a public Mathematica toolkit that provides analytical solutions to a wide set of problems in economics and finance. Many problems in economics and finance (iso elastic utility aka CES utility) require solving systems such as the one above. I need `Reduce[]` and not `Solve[]` because I need to add (linear) inequalities.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Reduce` rather than `Solve`? What are you hoping to get out at the end, if not the solution from `Solve`?

Comment: `Solve[Eliminate[eqns, z], {x, y}]`

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17127/45411) may (or may not) be useful.