# Wrong solution to a simple equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, bugs

The solution that `Solve` gives for this simple equation

```
(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x) == 6 - 18/(3 + x)
```

is `{{x -> -3}}`. Also `Reduce` gives `x == -3`. Why so?

Comment: **FullSimplify[(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x) == 6 - 18/(3 + x)]** gives **3+x==0**

Comment: @Cesareo: OK, and your comment is intended as a confirmation of the problem or as an answer? I think that this simplification is wrong.

Comment: @enzotib What should be the solution in your opinion?

Comment: Everyone, is the value of the LHS the same as the value of the RHS when x = -3? Alternatively, does the graph of the LHS intersect the graph of the RHS at x = -3?

Comment: @MarcoB: no solution, because `x=-3` make the denominator equal zero.

Comment: @Cesareo reductions with `FullSimplify` are true only generically and not always, and so in general there might be exceptions where the result is not true as is the case here. `Reduce` guffs up here either. The problem appears with `Reduce` since it should yield exceptional cases, or more clearly it should exclude incorrect results i.e.  check if the argument  belongs to the domain of function.

Comment: @Artes. Thanks for the explanation. We must always be vigilant and not accept the first result. Mainly when this is automatic.

Comment: A simpler version is: Reduce[x^2/x == 0, x], which returns x==0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue we encounter with the problem at hand one might consider as a bug in functionality for solving equations. `Solve` yields  generic solutions, while `Reduce` yields complete solutions or more properly a *complete solution space*. An extended discussion of the issue one can find in [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Nevertheless `Reduce` **implicitly assumes** that the variable is not restricted by the function domain. We need not classify this behavior as a bug, it depends on appropriate restriction of  `Reduce` usage.
In a comment above it was observed that `Apart[(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x)]` yielding `9 + x - 18/(3 + x)` might be reduced with the right hand side `6 - 18/(3 + x)` to get `3 + x == 0`.  **So does** `Reduce` while **it should not** since `x == -3` **does not belong to the function domain**.

```
Plot[{(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x), 6 - 18/(3 + x)}, {x, -12, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]
```

[image]

This inconsistent behavior might be eliminated by an appropriate use of `FunctionDomain` e.g. (by default the function domain is considered as a subset of `Reals`, and so we use `Complexes` to avoid any doubts)

```
Reduce[(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x) == 6 - 18/(3 + x) && 
        FunctionDomain[(9 + 12*x + x^2)/(3 + x) - (6 - 18/(3 + x)), x, Complexes],
        x]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Finally a sensible answer, I was beginning to think of being the only one to believe that this equation has no solutions. Thank you.

Comment: @enzotib  `Maple` gives empty solution(no solutions) :)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk +1 for Maple, then

Comment: It has a solution in the limit, i.e., `Limit[Subtract @@ eqn,  x -> -3]` evaluates to `0`, i.e., the curves intersect at `{-3, Infinity}` and `{-3, -Infinity}`

Comment: @enzotib Thanks, indeed this equation has no solutions, or if we redefine the concept of domain we would accept what `Reduce` says that `x == -3` is a correct answer.