# How is Mathematica treating $x^x$ when finding roots?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

When I enter

```
Solve[x (-x + x^x) == 0, {x}, Reals]
```

It returns three roots as

$$\{\{x\to -1\},\{x\to 1\},\{x\to 1\}\}$$

Is MMA treating

```
  Limit[x^x, x -> 0] = 1
```

Is that how it is getting that third root?

In some contexts, couldn't $x = 0$ also be a root?

I am using MMA 12.1. 1 on Windows 10, X86.

Comment: My guess is simply that it excludes 0 because `0^0` is `Indeterminate`, but I'm not sure. What's also weird to me is that it duplicates `{x -> 1}`...how does it count multiplicity here? Usually roots are duplciated for multiplicity reasons, e.g. `Solve[x^3 == 0, {x}]` gives three copies of `{x->0}`, but I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's define

```
f[x_]:= x ( -x + x^x)
```

now we have

```
FunctionDomain[ f[x], x]
```

> ```
> (x ∈ Integers && x <= -1) || x > 0
> ```

As we can see the both solutions returned by `Solve` belong to the domain of `f[x]` however `x == 0` does not belong to the domain and so it cannot be a solution. Here **the system works correctly** however **in a similar case it failed in a previous version and still does (at least in version *12.1*), see e.g. [Wrong solution to a simple equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211168/wrong-solution-to-a-simple-equation/211202#211202)**.

As it has been observed `x == 1` is a double root. Let's assume that `x > 0` than
`f[x] == 0` is equivalent to `Log[x] == x Log[x]`  and so `(x - 1) Log[x] == 0` and this equation has a double root at `x == 1` since $x-1=0$ and $\ln(x)=0$ for $x=1$.

**WARNING!!!**

Remarks above concern the case with  domain specification in `Reduce` and `Solve` e.g. `Solve[ f[x] == 0, x, Reals]` and `Reduce[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]` however when we restrict the domain by including appropriate ranges for the variable `x` both functions i.e. `Reduce` and `Solve` fail, e.g.

```
Solve[ f[x] == 0 && -2 <= Im[x] <= 2 && -6 < Re[x] < 6, x]
Reduce[f[x] == 0 && -2 <= Im[x] <= 2 && -6 < Re[x] < 6, x]
```

[image]

The correct solution `x == -1` is lost and a wrong "solution"  `x == 0` is included.

**This is a bug!**.

Comment: One might also point out that `x -> 1` is in fact a double root.  For example, `Series[x (-x + x^x), {x, 1, 2}]`,  or plotting.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks for this remark, nevertheless I guess that  my argument is even simpler.

Comment: @Artes: Thanks for this answer, however, why is it showing $x = 1$ twice? I am not following why it thinks there is a double root here. Is this a bug? You already explained the $x = 0$ case.

Comment: @Moo If $x>0$ then $f(x)=0 \equiv -x+x^x=0 \equiv -x+ e^{x \ln(x)}=0 \equiv \ln(x)= x \ln(x) \equiv (x-1)\ln(x)=0$. Now the both terms i.e. $(x-1)$ and $\ln(x)$ vanish at $x=1$. Right?