# Is this a bug in Reduce for x/Sin[x] == x?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

The output of

```
Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x]
```

is

```
(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == \[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1]) || x == 0
```

but x cannot be 0. Is this a bug?

Comment: if you do `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x, Reals]` then it does **not** give `x=0` (the default is complex domain). the question remains if $x=0$ is correct in the complex plane.  I have to look up my complex variables book.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLcim.png)

Comment: 0 is not a good result here although it is fine for the near-equivalent x=x*sin(x). Buglet, I guess.

Comment: It's wrong. Odd, since it does `Reduce[x/y == x]` and the follow-up `Reduce[Reduce[x/y == x] /. y -> Sin[x]]` correctly.

Comment: Oh, I think my example is misleading because `x/Sin[x]` automatically becomes `x*Csc[x]`.

Comment: `Reduce[ Sin[x]/x == 1/x] (*C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == \[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1]*) ` gives correct result too

Comment: In **Mathematica 13.0.1** Input `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x, x]` yields a correct result.  I guess that the equation in `Reduce` should be supplemented with `FunctionDomain` for an appropriate function as it has been discussed in [Wrong solution to a simple equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211168/wrong-solution-to-a-simple-equation/211202#211202). I guess that you have found another instance of the bug present there and so this post might be considered as a duplicate. Nevertheless +1.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to a set system option:

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];

Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x]
(*
C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == \[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1]
*)
```

It does not fix the buglet with `Csc[x]`, though:

```
Reduce[x*Csc[x] == x]
(*
(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == \[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1]) || x == 0
*)
```

Simpler example:

```
Reduce[x*Csc[x] == 0]
(*
x == 0
*)
```

Similar problems with other transcendental functions (`x*Log[x] == 0` and so on).

Comment: I have no problem in *version 13.0.1*, see comments below the question. +1.

Comment: More precisely in *ver. 13.0.1*  `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x]` yelds a wrong result (similarily `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x, Complexes]`) while `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x, x]` yields the correct one and so does `Reduce[x/Sin[x] == x, Reals]`.

Comment: @Artes That's a good point, which I forgot to consider: The difference between `Reduce[e]` and `Reduce[e,x]`....When I have time, I'll try to circle back and include an explanation of it in my answer.