# Problem with Solve and PrimeZetaP

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, number-theory, prime-numbers

I assume this is something to do with limits on numerical precision, but can someone explain the difference in output between these two `Solve` problems:

```
Solve[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.434, s]
```

> {{s -> 1.222683551}}

and

```
Solve[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.435, s]
```

> Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients 
>       or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers 
>       present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require 
>       exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may 
>       help.
>
> Solve[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.434, s]

Obviously, I've hit some kind of threshold - but what and why?

**UPDATE:**

Following @Artes's suggestion below, I tried

```
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.435, {s, 2}]
```

> {s -> 1.222402031}

Clearly, this works. But now *this*...

```
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.445, {s, 2}]
```

> {s -> 2.}

...doesn't.

There seems to be a threshold (call it `t`) somewhere in the region `1.434 < t < 1.44` where it becomes impossible to obtain a result, as this table shows:

```
TableForm[Table[
 {n, Solve[PrimeZetaP[s] == n, s], 
  FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == n, {s, 2}]}, 
 {n, 1.43, 1.44, 0.001}]]
```

Further thoughts, anyone? The error messages suggest I should use `Reduce` - but I'm not sure how to apply it in this instance; If I use `Reduce[PrimeZetaP[s] == n, s]` in the table above, I get nothing.

Comment: `Solve` works with exact numbers, however for transcendental functions it should be used with appropriate bounds on variables. See e.g. more detailed [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129). Nevertheless `Solve` cannot solve all equations involving transcendental functions. Try `FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == 1.435, {s, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks @Artes. I've updated the question above. There still seems to be some limit beyond which Mathematica simply cannot tackle the problem.

Comment: There will  always be some limits beyond which Mathematica simply cannot tackle many problems. The issues with `Solve` and `Reduce` are discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129). Read it carefully. There are some limits where `Solve` can call `NSolve`, it doesn't matter here since `FindRoot` is the way to go, `FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == 4.45, {s, 1.2}]`.

Comment: Thanks @Artes. Do you want to turn that into an answer so I can tick it?

Comment: I guess this problem comes from a simple mistake and can be simply found in the documentation and so the question might be closed or deleted as you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) needs a good initial estimate

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To get an initial estimate for `FindRoot`, find a fit for values of `{PrimeZetaP[s], s}`

```
data = Table[{PrimeZetaP[s], s}, {s, 1.1, 2, 0.01}];
```

Using [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)

```
f[p_] = a*p^2 + b*p + c /. FindFit[data,
   a*p^2 + b*p + c, {a, b, c}, p]

(* 2.59273 - 1.65311 p + 0.467891 p^2 *)
```

Looking at the fit

```
{pmin, pmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {0.452247, 2.10884} *)

Plot[f[p], {p, pmin, pmax}, Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Verifying that `FindRoot` works using better initial estimates

```
s /. FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s] == #, {s, f[#]},
    WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@
 Range[1.43`15, 1.44`15, 0.001`15]

(* {1.22381388261206, 1.22353066085125, 1.22324786557684, 1.22296549598819, \
1.22268355128654, 1.22240203067502, 1.22212093335863, 1.22184025854421, \
1.22156000544051, 1.22128017325810, 1.22100076120941} *)
```