# Solving an equation for a power of unknown variable

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

How do I solve an equation for a power of $t$, e.g. solving
$$-t(x–8)/8 = –2(x+4)/t$$
for $t^2$ instead of $t$, i.e. to get the answer
$$t^2=16(x+4)/(x–8)$$
from `Solve`?

I can solve it for $t$ easily and square $t$, but can it be done 'directly' using `Solve`? TIA.

Comment: Have you read the documentation pages of `Solve`?

Comment: Yes, but probably not every paragraph. Perhaps you can point the section which answers my question. I cannot find any suitable example in the text.

Comment: `Solve[{-t(x-8)/8==-2(x+4)/t, t^2==16(x+4)/(x-8)}, x]` should work, in case of doubts read this  post [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: `Solve[-t (x - 8)/8 == -2 (x + 4)/t, x]` yields `x -> (8 (8 + t^2))/(-16 + t^2)`. Is it what you want?

Comment: A small misunderstand due to my poor initial description. What I meant to ask was how to solve an equation with respect to t^p, e.g. t^2, and not t. Thus I would like to have ´Solve´ reply with the right hand side of t^2 = ... and not t = square root something. I hope this made it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[-t (x - 8)/8 == -2 (x + 4)/t /. t -> Sqrt[tt], tt] /. tt -> t^2

(*   {{t^2 -> (16 (4 + x))/(-8 + x)}}   *)

Equal @@ (First@First@sol)

(*   t^2 == (16 (4 + x))/(-8 + x)   *)
```

Or

```
Reduce[-t (x - 8)/8 == -2 (x + 4)/t /. t -> Sqrt[tt], tt] /. tt -> t^2

(*   -8 + x != 0 && 4 + x != 0 && t^2 == (16 (4 + x))/(-8 + x)   *)
```