# Solve gives no results, when used with parameter

Tags: equation-solving

In Wolfram Mathematica 12, when I enter:

```
Solve[ x == y , x]
```

I get:

```
{{x -> y}}
```

as expected.

But when I add an equation that contains only constants and parameters:

```
Solve[ x == y z && z == 1, x]
```

I get no results:

```
{}
```

when I want to get `{{x -> y}}` as before.

Comment: I think this is known and intentional. Try `Solve[x == y z && z == 1, {x, z}]` I think I saw question on this before on this site but can't be sure now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `Solve[x == y z && z == 1, {x, z}]` gives `{{x -> y, z -> 1}}`. This is (arguably more important) half of the answer. I would like to know why Mathematica behaves in this way.

Comment: You should evaluate `Solve[ x == y z && z == 1, x,MaxExtraConditions->All]`.  Your problem is a special case of a general issue which can be found in [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: see help, under possible issues. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/COQto.png)  `Solve[x == 1 && a == 2, x]` gives `{}`

Comment: You can also use either  `Solve[x == y z && z == 1, x, {z}]` or `Solve[Eliminate[x == y z && z == 1, z], x]`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, this is really helpful info. I should ask this question a long time ago ;)