# Is it possible to get a symbolic or numeric relation when solving a transcendental equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is the code.

```
Solve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, x, Reals]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica told me that  this system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
If not a symbolic relation, can a numeric relation be found?

**What's the numeric relation of x expressed in terms of a?**

Let's make up a numeric relation between $x$ and $a$.

$x \rightarrow 0.812a+\frac{1}{2}a^2 $

Anyone who have a better idea?

Comment: Similar questions were asked and answered a lot here. Try the numeric approach:`f[a_] := NSolve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, x, Reals];f[-1]` which results in `{{x -> -0.892312}, {x -> 3.04378}}`. Even `AsymptoticSolve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, {x}, {a, -1, 2}]` fails.

Comment: @user64494, why is there not a symbolic answer? Can you explain it?

Comment: @kile Transcendental equations generally do not yield to analytic closed-form solutions. They may do so sometimes when one of the independent variable tends to some limit (like $\rightarrow 0$ or $\rightarrow \infty$). You can find an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691896/approximate-solution-to-a-transcendental-equation-in-the-limit-of-a-variable)

Comment: This post should clarify your doubts [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve). In fact, given a numeric value to `a < -0.03475` you can find solution with `Solve`.

Comment: @Artes, is it possible to find the relation between x and a? For example, x=0.813a+0.7 a^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you insist on having **some** relation you can always use `FindFormula` note that from an analytic perspective this is not the "correct" answer.

```
sols = Table[
   Flatten@{a, 
     x /. Solve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == -a, x, Reals]}, {a, 1, 
    100}];
branch1 = sols[[All, {1, 2}]];
branch2 = sols[[All, {1, 3}]];
formula1 = FindFormula[branch1, a];
formula2 = FindFormula[branch2, a];
```

Now you have some formulas `formula1` and `formula2` which might be helpful or not.

Comment: It is funny---some formulas... In what domain are they accurate?

Comment: Well, you can choose the domain of accuracy by setting the range of `a` in the definition of `sols`. I am not sure about this problem, but in general the solutions will be only valid in that domain and complete nonsense outside.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just a long comment.

By making small Manipulate, it shows that no real solution exist when $a$ gets over value of around $-1/10$.   Hard to determine the exact value of $a$ but using the slider you can get very close to finding it. i.e when $a$ is larger than that limit, it never crosses the x-axis, so no real solution exist.

```
ClearAll[a,x];
eq = (1 - Exp[x] + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) - a;
Manipulate[Plot[eq /. a -> a0, {x, -3, 3}],
 {{a0, 0, "a"}, -1, 1, .001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0}
 ]
```

[image]

I think this might explain why Solve could not do it in addition to the other comments above.

Comment: Is it possible to find the relation between "a" and "x"? Like x= 0.813a + a^2

Comment: @kile well, the relation is the equation itself? which is echoed back when you type `Solve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, {a, x}, Reals]` Make sure to add `a` in `Solve` here.

Comment: That's what I get when input your code. `a -> 1/4 (2/x - (2 E^x)/x + 3 x)`. Still, This is not what I want. what I want is `x->...a` is expressed in terms of a.

Comment: @kile Ok, misunderstood you. There is no equation to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$ I am afraid. If you try by hand, you'll see why. The equation is not polynomial so no exact formula exist.  If you have specific numerical value for a, it can do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = (1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a;
```

The numeric solution for a given value of `a` and an initial estimate is given by [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
f[a_?NumericQ, init_?NumericQ] :=
 FindRoot[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, {x, init}]

pt1 = ({x, a} /. f[a, -10]) /. a -> -6 // Quiet

(* {-7.91581, -6} *)

pt2 = ({x, a} /. f[a, 3]) /. a -> -6 // Quiet

(* {4.42428, -6} *)
```

To find the max value of `a`

```
xa = Solve[D[eqn[[1]], x] == 0, x, Reals][[1]]

(* {x -> Root[{-2 + E^#1*(2 - 2*#1) + 
             3*#1^2 & , 
    1.554653058468533267935\
     17428741457642172`20.286009576768794}]} *)
```

The exact value is a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression.

The maximum value of `a` is then

```
amax = a /. Solve[eqn /. xa, a, Reals][[1]]

(* (1 - E^Root[{-2 + E^#1*(2 - 2*#1) + 
                3*#1^2 & , 
      1.55465305846853326793\
       517428741457642172`20.286009576768794}] + 
      (3/2)*Root[{-2 + E^#1*(2 - 2*#1) + 
                  3*#1^2 & , 
       1.5546530584685332679\
        3517428741457642172`20.286009576768794}]^
          2)/(2*Root[{-2 + E^#1*(2 - 2*#1) + 
              3*#1^2 & , 
     1.554653058468533267935\
      17428741457642172`20.286009576768794}]) *)
```

The `{x, a}` point for max `a` is

```
(pt = {x, amax} /. xa) // N

(* {1.55465, -0.0347424} *)
```

where [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) has converted the `Root` expressions to their approximate numeric values.

[`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) shows the solutions to the equation

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, -13, 5}, {a, -10, 0},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ {pt1, pt2},
   Red, Tooltip[Point[#], #] &[N@pt]},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, a})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsymptoticSolve` to get a solution near `x=k` as following:

```
    AsymptoticSolve[(1 - E^x + (3 x^2)/2)/(2 x) == a, {x, k}, {a, (1 - E^k + (3 
    k^2)/2)/(2 k), 2}]

    (*{{x -> k + (4 k^2 (a - (1 - E^k + (3 k^2)/2)/(2 k)))/(-2 + 2 E^k - 2 E^k k + 
 3 k^2) + (16 k^3 (-2 + 2 E^k - 2 E^k k + E^k k^2) (a - (1 - E^k + (3 k^2)/2)/(2 k))^2)/(-2 + 2 E^k - 2 E^k k + 
  3 k^2)^3}}*)
```

Comment: So what is $k$ ?