# No Solution For Solve with Free Variable

Tags: equation-solving, variable

Mathematica returns no solutions for this simple query:

```
Solve[a*x == x && x != 0, {x}]
(* output: {} *)
```

Clearly, when `a` is `1`, any `x` is a solution. Therefore, I would expect the solution to involve a case distinction over `a`.

What is Mathematica solving here exactly? I was thinking it would try to find `x` that satisfies the equation for all `a`, but then this should not return any solution either (but it does):

```
Solve[x == a, {x}]
(* output: {{x -> a}} *)
```

Comment: You can try using Reduce instead of Solve.

Comment: @CarlWoll Using Reduce makes sense for me, thanks for the hint! Still, I would like to understand what Solve does in this case. If I cannot interpret the output of Solve correctly (`{}` in this case), I will not be able to use it in more complex cases where I cannot verify the result.

Comment: This issue had been discussed several times. For an extended discussion see [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129). `Solve` without any options cannot yield a full dimensional component while `Reduce` can. Use `MaxExtraConditions->All` option in `Solve`.

Comment: @Artes Perfect, thanks for the pointer (I did not find this before, as I did not know what to look for exactly). My take-away message is that Solve may omit some solutions, unless I provide the flag `MaxExtraConditions -> All`. Then, my example yields a warning which tells me to try Reduce.

Comment: @Peter `Solve`  is less powerful  than `Reduce`in various cases (exceptional or full-dimensional ones). Take a look at the link in my comment.