# Why does Solve produce a result in terms of one variable, but not the other?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following quartic equation:\begin{equation}
x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + ax + 1 = 0
\end{equation} and I'm trying to find relations for $a$ and $b$ for which we have multiple roots. To this end, I set

```
x1 = -(a/4)-1/4 Sqrt[8+a^2-4 b]-1/2 Sqrt[-2+a^2/2-b-(-8 a-a^3+4 a b)/(2 Sqrt[8+a^2-4 b])]
x3 = -(a/4)+1/4 Sqrt[8+a^2-4 b]-1/2 Sqrt[-2+a^2/2-b+(-8 a-a^3+4 a b)/(2 Sqrt[8+a^2-4 b])]
```

and I use Solve to get expressions for $b$ in terms of $a$, which satisfy $x_{1}=x_{3}$:

```
In[156]:= Solve[x1 == x3, b]
Out[156]= {}
```

It says that there is no solution. Then, I try to solve for $a$:

```
In[143]:= Solve[x1 == x3, a]
Out[143]= {{a -> -2 Sqrt[-2 + b]}, {a -> 2 Sqrt[-2 + b]}}
```

It does produce a solution. Now, I managed to get the solution for $b$ if I allow an extra condition:

```
In[152]:= Solve[x1 == x3, b, MaxExtraConditions -> 1] 
During evaluation of In[152]:=Solve::useq: The answer found by Solve contains equational condition(s) 
0==Indeterminate,0==Indeterminate,0==Indeterminate,0==Indeterminate}. A likely reason for this is that the 
solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.
Out[152]= {{b -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (8 + a^2), Indeterminate == 0 || Indeterminate == 0]}}
```

which, I believe, is because at $b=\frac{1}{4}\left(8+a^{2}\right)$ $$\frac{-8 a - a^3 + 4 a b}{2\sqrt{8 + a^2 - 4 b}} = \frac{0}{0}$$ However, the same holds for $a = \pm2\sqrt{-2+b}$ and yet, no extra conditions are needed to solve for $a$. Could someone explain to me why that is? Thanks.

Comment: try `Solve[x1 == x3, b, Reals]` then it gives solution.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xr2y.png)  V 12.3.1

Comment: You shouldn't treat the output of `Solve` as always valid, see e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)  Your problem should become clear having read the output of `Solve[x1 == x3, b, MaxExtraConditions -> All]` or simply `Reduce[x1 == x3, b]`.

Comment: @Artes Those give me conditions on `Indeterminate == 0`. Do you get the same? That should not happen. Looks like a bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs  Conditions of the form `Indeterminate == 0` are not mathematically correct, nonetheless I wouldn't classify any warnings as bugs.  However I could say such warnings and  conditions point out the source of the problem, i.e. that the reasonning when solving `Solve[x1 == x3, a]` and `Solve[x1 == x3, b]` are not quite "symmetric".

Answer (score 3):

Try the code

```
poly = x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + a x + 1;
soln = Solve[Discriminant[poly, x] == 0];
Print[soln // InputForm]
Print[poly /. soln // Factor // InputForm]
(* {{b -> -2 - 2*a}, {b -> -2 + 2*a}, {b -> (8 + a^2)/4}} *)
(* {(-1 + x)^2*(1 + 2*x + a*x + x^2),
    (1 + x)^2*(1 - 2*x + a*x + x^2), 
    (2 + a*x + 2*x^2)^2/4} *)
```

The reason is that setting the discriminant to zero is precisely
the condition to have multiple roots.

Comment: Note that the last polynomial only has complex roots for $|a| < 4$.  This may or may not be important depending on the problem the OP wants to solve.