# Why does Solve return an empty list?

Tags: equation-solving, coefficients

Code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
equ = -(v*\[Sigma]*(k+i*v+j*w-w*\[Sigma]))/(-1-\[Sigma])+i*(-v*\[Beta]+(k+i*v+w+j*w)*(k+i*v+j*w-w*\[Sigma]))+j*(w*(-1-\[Sigma])+(v*(k+i*v+j*w-w*\[Sigma])/(-1-\[Sigma])))

v1 = Coefficient[equ,v];
v2 = Coefficient[equ,v^2];
v3 = Coefficient[equ,v^3];
v4 = Coefficient[equ,v^4];
v5 = Coefficient[equ,v^5];
w1 = Coefficient[equ,w];
w2 = Coefficient[equ,w^2];
w3 = Coefficient[equ,w^3];
w4 = Coefficient[equ,w^4];
w5 = Coefficient[equ,w^5];
nic = Coefficient[equ,v,0];

Solve[{v1==0,v2==0,v3==0,v4==0,v5==0,w1==0,w2==0,w3==0,w4==0,w5==0,nic==0},{i,j,k}]
```

So I have this function:

[image]

where $v, w$ are the variables here and $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are parameters.

What I'm doing is I try to calculate such $i,j,k$ that the coefficients of that function will be equal to zero.

But instead of the solution, Mathematica is returning an empty list. Why?

I don't see any mistake here in the code

Comment: If you use `Reduce` rather than `Solve` you get solutions with conditions on some of the parameters.

Comment: One can use also  `Solve[{v1 == 0, v2 == 0, w1 == 0, w2 == 0, nic == 0}, {i, j, k}, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> All]` to find possible solutions.  See e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve)

Comment: I am guessing that the idea is that `v1` will extract the coefficient of $v^1 w^0$, but that is not true, `v1` still contains `w`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try different approaches. In principle, [SolveAlways](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) does exactly what OP wants:

```
SolveAlways[equ==0,{v,w}]
(* {{j->-1,σ->-1},
    {j->-1,σ->-1},
    {j->-1,σ->-1},
    {j->-1,σ->-1},
    {j->-1,σ->-1},
    {j->-1,σ->-1},
    {i->0,j->0,σ->0},
    {i->0,j->0,σ->0},
    {i->0,j->0,σ->0},
    {j->0,σ->0,i->0}} *)
```

It is a little irritating that the same solution is returned multiple times (I use V12.3 if it matters). It also includes solutions where $\sigma=-1$ which make little sense in view of the $1+σ$ denominators. Taking this into account, this yields `{i->0,j->0,σ->0}` as the solution, with $k$ and $\beta$ arbitrary.

If one extracts coefficients by hand, one must be careful because there are also mixed terms such as `v*w`. The simplest way to extract all coefficients, given that `equ` is a polynomial in $v$ and $w$, is probably [CoefficientRules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html?q=CoefficientRules):

```
cs = CoefficientRules[equ,{v,w}][[;;,2]]
(* {i^3-(i j)/(1+σ)+(i σ)/(1+σ),
    i^2+2 i^2 j-i^2 σ-j^2/(1+σ)+(2 j σ)/(1+σ)-σ^2/(1+σ),
    2 i^2 k-i β-(j k)/(1+σ)+(k σ)/(1+σ),
    i j+i j^2-i σ-i j σ,
    -j+i k+2 i j k-j σ-i k σ,
    i k^2}
*)
```

Just calling [Solve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve) yields no solutions:

```
Solve[cs==0,{i,j,k}]
(* {} *)
```

This is consistent with the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve):

> Solve gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed.

The word *parameters* refers to $\sigma$ and $\beta$ in this case, because we have not listed them as variables. Therefore `{}` tells us that for generic values of $\sigma$ and $\beta$ there are no solutions, which is true.

To treat $\sigma$ and $\beta$ not as parameters but as variables, use

```
Solve[cs==0,{i,j,k,σ,β}]
(* {{i->0,j->0,σ->0},
    {i->0,j->0,k->0,σ->0}} and a warning *)
```

This produces two solutions, but the second is really a special case of the first, therefore the only solution is

```
{i->0,j->0,σ->0}
```

Again, $k$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary.

One can also use pencil and paper to verify that (for $\sigma \neq -1$) this is the only solution, start from $ik^2 = 0$ (see the last entry of `cs`) to see that either $i$ or $k$ must be zero, then consider `cs/.{i->0}` and `cs/.{k->0}` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So this means, that we can't find a solution for specific $i, j, k$? Because originally this exercise was about this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584278/computing-a-center-manifold , and I actually need to find specific values for $i,j,k$ while $\beta$ and $\sigma$ remain arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, given say $\sigma=0.1$ and $\beta=0.3$, there are no three numbers $i,j,k$ such that `equ` vanishes for all $v,w$. (Same for other values of $\sigma$ and $\beta$, except $\sigma = 0$.) Regarding your other post, I will not get involved there, but I think you should try to find an example where people make a center manifold calculation, maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714564/center-manifold-theorem-example). It will probably be easier if you first try to get the intuition, then attempt the calculation.