# Finding the equation of a circle for complex numbers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

```
Solve[Abs[z]²==1,z]
```

returns two solutions, -1, and 1. I would like to get all the solutions of the
form `Exp[I c₁]`.

```
Solve[Abs[z]²==1,z,Complexes]
```

Does not help either.

I can do

```
Solve[z Conjugate[z]==1,z,Complexes]
```

But then Mathematica complains about the solution containing a full-dimensional component.

Obviously the purpose of the question here isn't to characterize the solution (which is known) but to learn a little more about how Mathematica internals think about this.

Comment: One should exploit `Reduce` rather than `Solve` in such cases. More on this topic one can find here [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: the  format of `2` is wrong.