# This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find a solution for $N$ for the following equation.

$$ \frac{\exp(-\sigma^2/2)}{(1 - \exp(-\sigma^2/2))} - \exp(-(N^2-3N+3)\sigma^2/2) \frac{(N-1 + \exp(-N \sigma^2/2) - N \exp(-\sigma^2/2))}{((1 - \exp(-\sigma^2/2))^2 N} < \epsilon $$

So, I just checked for a solution where it is equal to $\epsilon$.

```
Solve[Exp[-S^2/2]/(1 - Exp[-S^2/2]) - 
   Exp[-(N^2 - 3 N + 3) S^2/2] (N - 1 + Exp[-N S^2/2] - 
       N Exp[-S^2/2])/((1 - Exp[-S^2/2])^2 N ) ==  p, N]
```

I get the following error.

> ```
> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
> ```

Comment: Use `n` not `N` because capital `N` is a builtin. In any case, this equation is too complex to solve using `Solve`. I'm assuming you want a fully symbolic solution and you haven't got numerical values for `S` etc. ?

Comment: Yes, I want a full symbolic solution and I haven't tried with a single $S$ .

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe a compact symbolic solution should exist? It looks to me like it's just too complicated for Mathematica.

Comment: I just tried with $n$ and a value for $S$ as $3$. Still the same error. I think it is too complex to find a solution.

Comment: Not really. I do not know for sure if it has a direct solution. I was just trying if it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For convenience we define:

```
f[n_, s_] := Exp[-s^2/2]/(1 - Exp[-s^2/2]) - 
             Exp[-(n^2 - 3 n + 3) s^2/2] (n - 1 + Exp[-n s^2/2] - 
                                           n Exp[-s^2/2])/((1 - Exp[-s^2/2])^2 n)
```

One can simply visualize solutions with e.g.

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f[n, s] == p, {n, -2, 4}, {s, 0, 6}, 
  ContourStyle -> Thick, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {p, 0, 1, 1/10000}]
```

and then it is straightforward to find a symbolic solutions prescribing appropriate parameters `s` and `p`, e.g.

```
With[{p = 3/10000, s = 4}, Solve[f[n, s] == p, n, Reals]]
```

[image]

These are exact solutions expressed in terms of `Root` objects and they cannot be expressed analytically in terms of radicals, see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768). For more detalied discussion of a powerful function `Solve` see e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

```
pp = Thread[{With[{p = 3/10000}, SolveValues[f[n, 4] == p, n, Reals]],4}];
With[{p = 3/10000}, 
  ContourPlot[{f[n, s] == p, s == 4}, {n, 0, 5/2}, {s, 2, 9/2}, 
    ContourStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pp]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The method below is focused mainly on the case where $N$ is integer (which OP confirms is the case in the comment below)

You can get a symbolic function/expression if you solve for $\sigma$ with the caveat that you will have to consider a finite set of explicit integers.

Notice that for a fixed $N$, say $N=3$, you have a polynomial equation if you change variables and rearrange the equation like this :

```
f[n, s] - ϵ /. s -> Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-Log[z]] /. n -> 3 // 
   Together // Numerator // Simplify
```

$$-z^5-z^4+2 z^3-3 z (\epsilon +1)+3 \epsilon$$

The above equation should equate to zero.

You do not have to use a change of variables however, you can solve the equation directly.

Here is a function to generate nmax solutions:

```
table[nmax_] := 
 Table[{n -> m, 
   Refine[Solve[{f[m, s] == ϵ, s > 0}, s, 
     Reals], ϵ > 0]}, {m, nmax}]
```

The three first solution for $N\in\{1,2,3\} $:

**Important note !** : **$\sigma$  positive** below is left as a means to simplify the discussion below but you should remove it in your code. See important footnote in bold at the end.

```
table[4]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n\to 1 & \left\{\left\{s\to \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\log \left(\frac{\epsilon +1}{\epsilon }\right)}\right\}\right\} \\
 n\to 2 & \left\{\left\{s\to \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{4 \epsilon ^2+12 \epsilon +1}+2 \epsilon +1}{4 \epsilon }\right)}\right\}\right\} \\
 n\to 3 & \left\{\left\{s\to \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\log \left(\text{Root}\left[3 \text{$\#$1}^5 \epsilon +\text{$\#$1}^4 (-3 \epsilon -3)+2 \text{$\#$1}^2-\text{$\#$1}-1\&,1\right]\right)}\right\}\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The first two are explicit and the third involves the root of a quintic which can not be solved in terms of radicals but it can be solved in terms of hypergeometric functions as shown in this Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Other_characterizations

The next root involves the solution to a polynomial of degree 10. Maybe one can find an explicit solution but for the question here you do not need to and in general functions based from `Root` are **full fledged symbolic** functions for which you can find series expansions at small and large arguments, locate singularities symbolically with [`FunctionSingularities`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionSingularities.html) and much more. You just might have trouble with integration which such functions but that is not the question here.

Consider now a value for $\epsilon$ such as $\epsilon=0.4$

```
table[4] /. ϵ -> 0.4
```

`(* {{n -> 1, {{s -> 1.58289}}}, {n -> 2, {{s -> 1.41233}}}, {n -> 3, {{s -> 1.56111}}}, {n -> 4, {{s -> 1.58272}}}} *)`

We can plot `s`=$\sigma$ for 10 values of `n`=$N$ with $\epsilon=0.4$

**Note**: Takes a while you might want to store the generated list if you plan to plot a lot with a fixed value of nmax

```
table[10] // Map[{n, s} /. {#[[1]], #[[2, 1, 1]]} &] // 
ReplaceAll[\[Epsilon] -> 0.4] // ListPlot
```

[image]

We can also plot $\sigma$=`s` for different $N$ as a function of $\epsilon$ where each curve is labeled by the value of $N$:

```
table[4] // Map[{s, n} /. {#[[1]], #[[2, 1, 1]]} &] // 
  MapApply[Callout] // Plot[#, {ϵ, 0, 0.5}] &
```

[image]

---

**Important footnote**

I imagine that `s`=$\sigma$>0 imposes that the solution is positive for any $\epsilon$. In that case, one is excluding solutions that are positive or negative depending on the value of $\epsilon$. To be safe one should perhaps remove the $\sigma$>0 constraint above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. And, yes I should have mentioned the constraints like $\sigma > 0$ and $N$ is an integer.

Comment: @CfourPiO Actually, imposing $\sigma>0$ might exclude solutions that are positive or negative depending on the value of $\epsilon$. Hence, that constraint should be removed in the scenario of the code above.

Comment: @CfourPiO I made an edit but maybe don't bother much with it, I just did some cleaning and removed the claim that Root with a transcendental function is not really symbolic. What I meant is that you did not have a function depending on another variable just a single number for a given choice of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.