# How to solve this trigonometric function equation?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

```
Solve[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 α]] == Cos[α]/(2 - Sin[α]), 
       tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α], 
       0 < α < π/2}, tanα, {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}]
```

It returns `{{t -> ConditionalExpression[Tan[\[Alpha]],  0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/4 || \[Pi]/4 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2]}}`, which is incorrect.

the correct answer is `tan α=√15/15`

Comment: It looks like alpha became x in the solve variables.

Comment: ```Solve[{TrigFactor[Tan[2 \[Alpha]]] == 
   Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), 
  t == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
  0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, t, {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}]```The result calculated in this way is also incorrect

Comment: One should evaluate `Solve[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 α]] == Cos[α]/(2 - Sin[α]), 
       tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α], 0 < α < π/2}, tanα, {Sin[α], Cos[α]},  MaxExtraConditions -> All]` or `Reduce[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 α]] == Cos[α]/(2 - Sin[α]), tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α], 0 < α < π/2}, tanα]`.  Why it should be is explained in [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: @Artes The results obtained from both of your methods are incorrect. The real situation is that we cannot calculate the result

Comment: It returns "Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition 0<\[Alpha]<\[Pi]/2, the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information." and `{}`  in 13.2.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @csn899  The both results are correct... You simply incorrectly use such a sophisticated function as `Solve`.

Comment: @Artes ```tan\[Alpha] -> 
 ConditionalExpression[Tan[\[Alpha]], 0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2]```the answer is incorrect

Comment: @csn899  Why is it incorrect, have I missed anything?

Comment: In 13.2.1 the command from your latest edit produces "Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition 0<\[Alpha]<\[Pi]/2, the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information." and `{}`.

Comment: @Artes Did not calculate the final real number solution

Comment: @csn899  Once more: **the result is correct**.  You litter up this site!   I pointed it out you incorrectly demand full information from `Solve`.  It works correctly.  You haven't read the link I provided. All what you need can be found there.

Comment: Not certain, but maybe this is along the lines of what is wanted? `In[128]:= 
tpolys0 = 
  Numerator[
   Together[{TrigExpand[Tan[2*alf]] - Cos[alf]/(2 - Sin[alf]), 
     tan*Cos[alf] - Sin[alf]}]];
tpolys = Join[tpolys0 /. {Sin[_] -> s, Cos[_] -> c}, {c^2 + s^2 - 1}]

Out[129]= {-c (c^2 - 4 s + s^2), -s + c tan, -1 + c^2 + s^2}

In[131]:= Solve[tpolys == 0, tan, {c, s}]

Out[131]= {{tan -> -(1/Sqrt[15])}, {tan -> 1/Sqrt[15]}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your latest edit is last. The following works.

```
Reduce[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 \[Alpha]]] == 
Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), tan\[Alpha] == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
  0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, tan\[Alpha]]
```

> `\[Alpha] == 2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]] &&  tan\[Alpha] == Sin[2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]]/ Cos[2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]]`

Comment: `Sin[2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]]/Cos[2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]] == Sqrt[15]/15` performs `True`.

Comment: ```Reduce[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 \[Alpha]]] == 
    Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), 
   tan\[Alpha] == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, tan\[Alpha]] // FullSimplify```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it that sometimes a solution can solve a trigonometric function equation, and sometimes a reduce is used when it cannot be solved?

Comment: `Reduce` is  a more powerful command than `Solve` as  noticed in the documentation.

Comment: ```Reduce[{(2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Sin[\[Alpha]])/(
    Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]^2) == Cos[\[Alpha]]/(
    2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), tan\[Alpha] == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, 
  tan\[Alpha], {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}] // FullSimplify```

Comment: ```Reduce[{(2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Sin[\[Alpha]])/(
    Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]^2) == Cos[\[Alpha]]/(
    2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), tan\[Alpha] == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, tan\[Alpha]] // FullSimplify```

Comment: The same result as in my answer is produced by `Reduce[{TrigExpand[Tan[2 \[Alpha]]] == 
   Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]), 
  tan\[Alpha] == Sin[\[Alpha]]/Cos[\[Alpha]], 
  0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2}, {tan\[Alpha], \[Alpha]}]`.

Comment: Is there any reason why this```{Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]} ``` can lead to the ability to calculate the correct result?

Comment: @csn899  Sorry, don't understand you. Please present the whole working command.

Answer (score 3):

Weierstrass substitution `\[Alpha] -> 2 ArcTan[u]` gives the solution

```
eq = Tan[2 \[Alpha]] ==Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]) /. \[Alpha] -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand // Simplify
(*1/2 (-1 + u^2) (1/(1 - u + u^2) - (8 u)/(1 - 6 u^2 + u^4)) == 0*)

solu=Solve[eq, u]  (* four solutions! *)
(*{{u -> -1}, {u -> 1}, {u -> 4 - Sqrt[15]}, {u -> 4 + Sqrt[15]}}*)

alfa=Tan[2 ArcTan[u]] /. solu // TrigExpand // Simplify
(* {-(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2, 2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]], 2 ArcTan[4 +Sqrt[15]]} *)

Plot[{Tan[2 \[Alpha]],Cos[\[Alpha]]/(2 - Sin[\[Alpha]])}, {\[Alpha], -Pi, Pi},GridLines -> { alfa , None}]
```

[image]

result `Tan[\[Alpha]]`

```
Map[Tan,alfa]
(*{ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, Tan[2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]],Tan[2 ArcTan[4 + Sqrt[15]]]}*)
```

Comment: You omitted an equation `tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α]` in your `eq`.

Comment: `tan\[Alpha]` is a variable to solve.

Comment: @user644494 I don't need this extra equation `tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α]` and gave the result for `Tan[\[Alpha]]`!

Comment: However, the system from the question is `{TrigExpand[Tan[2 α]] == Cos[α]/(2 - Sin[α]), 
       tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α], 
       0 < α < π/2}`. You also do not take into account `0 < α < π/2`.

Comment: @user64494 Your last three comments are completely neglectable! My solution covers the  complete  range `-Pi<\[Alpha]<Pi`, QP surely might select the solutions he is interested in.

Comment: Also it is not a good practice to seriously edit a post, not indicating the changes.

Comment: I have expanded my answer  due to YOUR first two comments, which showed me that you didn't unterstand my answer. And now I'm out of discussion!

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Solve[{Tan[2 α] == Cos[α]/(2 - Sin[α]), 
    tanα == Sin[α]/Cos[α], 0 < α < π/2}, 
   tanα, MaxExtraConditions -> All] // FullSimplify

(* {{tanα -> 
   ConditionalExpression[1/Sqrt[15], α == 2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]]]}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
alpha = Rule @@ sol[[1, 1, -1, -1]]

(* α -> 2 ArcTan[4 - Sqrt[15]] *)

Tan[α] /. alpha // FullSimplify

(* 1/Sqrt[15] *)
```