# Solving a-two-variable equation in primes

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, theorem-proving

How solve the following equation in *Mathematica* (preferably in one line) for pairs of $(x,y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ are primes?

$x^3-y^4=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, this can be done in one line:

```
FindInstance[x^3 - y^4 == 1, {x, y}, Primes]
```

> `{}`

No solution in the primes.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working on WolframAlpha page.

Answer (score 6):

`FindInstance` cannot prove that there are no solutions, especially when the domain of solutions is the set of primes.
More acceptable approach would be:

```
Reduce[x^3 - y^4 == 1, {x, y}, Primes]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

or

```
Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, x^3 - y^4 == 1 ], Primes]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Nonetheless neither `Reduce` nor `Resolve` with `Exists` can work successfully in general (with different equations) with `Primes`.  This issue is quite similar to difficulty of deciding whether the Collatz conjecture is true or false.

Let's prove the theorem  mathematically.  We can see that both $x$ and $y$ cannot be both odd, neither both even since $x^3-y^4$ is odd, and so one of them has to be even, the only even can be $y=2$ since $2^3-y^4<0$ for any prime $y$.
Now $x^3=2^4+1=17$ cannot be satisfied for any whole number $x$. QED.

Comment: Up to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html?q=FindInstance) (see Properties and RElation section),"When there are no solutions, FindInstance returns an empty list:" and (see  Details and Options) "`FindInstance` may be able to find instances even if Reduce cannot give a complete reduction."

Comment: However, +1 for your answer.

Comment: @user64494 It's natural that `FindInstance` returns an empty list when there are no solutions, otherwise it would be useless.  In our case we need proving that there are no solutions and for this task, `Reduce` or `Resolve` are more suitable since e.g. `Reduce` returns  boolean formulae while `FindInstance` returns replacement rules and the former is appropriate for complete description of solution sets, for this issue see e.g. in [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)