# Trying to Solve system of equations gives empty result

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

First-time user of Mathematica. I have three equations, and I'm trying to solve for one of the variables.
I'm hoping this is just a syntax problem.

```
eq1 = a^3*c + c^3*a == (a + (1 - f)*d)^3*b + b^3*(a + (1 - f)*d);
eq2 = g == c - b; 
eq3 = (e - d)/(a + d) == g/b;
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, d]
```

But it results in just empty output:

[image: the result is just an empty squiggly-braces]

Comment: In fact `Solve` should not yield the empty set of solutions.  For more detailed discussion see e.g.  [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).  We can get rid of trivial equation `eq2` and set `h` in place of `a + (1 - f)*d` . Then use `Reduce[{a^3 c + a c^3 == b^3 h + b h^3, (-d + e)/(a + d) == (c - b)/
   b}, h]`

Comment: @Artes, that's some beneficial information. I was often frustrated with `Solve` not giving reasonable answers. This post goes in-depth into why this happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Artes Would I give `h` to to Reduce or `d` though?

Comment: It would be a bug if Solve did something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {
   eq1 = a^3*c + c^3*a == (a + (1 - f)*d)^3*b + b^3*(a + (1 - f)*d),
   eq2 = g == c - b,
   eq3 = (e - d)/(a + d) == g/b};

vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]]

(* {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} *)
```

**Option 1:** [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for three variables (including d) and disregard unwanted solutions. For example,

```
sol1a = d -> # & /@ (d /. Solve[eqns, {d, a, b}]);
```

There are multiple lengthy solutions.

```
#[sol1a] & /@ {Length, LeafCount}

(* {3, 17664} *)
```

or,

```
sol1b = d -> # & /@ (d /. Solve[eqns, {d, b, c}]);

#[sol1b] & /@ {Length, LeafCount}

{6, 2215}
```

**Option 2:** Solve for d and eliminate two other variables. For example,

```
sol2a = Solve[eqns, d, {a, b}];

#[sol2a] & /@ {Length, LeafCount}

(* {3, 17667} *)
```

or,

```
sol2b = Solve[eqns, d, {b, c}];

#[sol2b] & /@ {Length, LeafCount}

(* {6, 2221} *)
```

**Option 3:** Solve for d and use the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

```
(sol3 = SolveValues[eqns, d, MaxExtraConditions -> All])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Could I narrow down the resulting solutions by assuming all the vars would be real numbers greater than zero? Also I'm trying to result in an equation which I can eventually type into python, so when the solution has several `||` and `Root` and `#`, then I don't even know where to begin with that. It seems that option 3 is closer to what I'm looking for, right?

Comment: Just include the constraints in the `Solve`, e.g., `sol1c = d -> # & /@ (d /. Solve[Join[eqns, {vars \[Element] PositiveReals}], {d, a, b}]) // ToRadicals;`

Answer (score 4):

It's not a simple system of equations. There might be elegant methods. I present a more brute-force one:

```
eq4 = eq3 /. g -> (-b + c) // Simplify

c = c /. Solve[eq4, c][[1]]

Solve[eq1, d] // Simplify
```

Or using `Eliminate` to make it a one-liner:

```
Solve[Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {g, c}], d]
```

Or, as suggested by @Artes, using Reduce can even give some rational answers too instead of Root objects:

```
Reduce[Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {g, b}], d]
```

To convert `Root` objects to usual form just use `ToRadicals`. As an illustration:

```
sol = Reduce[Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {g, b}], d];

so[[3, 2, 1]] // ToRadicals
```

Comment: Did you mean `Reduce[Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {g, b}], d]`? Also can I reduce the number of solutions by telling it all my vars are >0?

Comment: And, I was hoping to just get a normal equation for d in terms of the other variables, however I get this long equation with boolean operators, so how do I even work with that?

Comment: @DansAltamira ah my mistake I forgot to add `Reduce`. The long equation actually contains root objects which you can easily convert to normal form using `ToRadicals`. And yes it is a better practice to define all the assumptions for your variables. If they are global variables used throughout the notebook you can use something like `$Assumptions = {{a, b, c, d} \[Element] Reals, {a, b, c, d} > 0}` or if they are local you just use `Assuming` within `Solve`. Let me edit my answer to highlight that.